# Why can't I use background image and color together?

Tags: css, background-image, background-color

What I am trying to do is to show both `background-color` and `background-image`, so that half of my `div` will cover the right shadow background image, and the other left part will cover the background color.

But when I use `background-image`, the color disappears.

Comment: What's your CSS code?

Answer (score 322, accepted):

It's perfectly possible to use both a color and an image as background for an element.

You set the `background-color` and `background-image` styles. If the image is smaller than the element, you need to use the `background-position` style to place it to the right, and to keep it from repeating and covering the entire background you use the `background-repeat` style:

```
background-color: green;
background-image: url(images/shadow.gif);
background-position: right;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Or using the composite style `background`:

```
background: green url(images/shadow.gif) right no-repeat;
```

If you use the composite style `background` to set both separately, only the last one will be used, that's one possible reason why your color is not visible:

```
background: green; /* will be ignored */
background: url(images/shadow.gif) right no-repeat;
```

There is no way to specifically limit the background image to cover only part of the element, so you have to make sure that the image is smaller than the element, or that it has any transparent areas, for the background color to be visible.

Comment: How do i get this working. I want to use `background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(222,222,222) 19%, rgb(201,201,201) 50%, rgb(219,219,219) 80%); AND background-image: url(icon.png) no-repeat right;` How do i apply both the gradient and the image-icon. Please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504071/is-it-possible-to-combine-a-background-image-and-css3-gradients

Comment: RE: @AnishNair - The `background:` is shorthand and then assumes there is no image specified and walks over the `background-image`

Comment: This is what was causing me issues - Thanks! 
_If you use the composite style background to set both separately, only the last one will be used, that's one possible reason why your color is not visible:_

Answer (score 35):

To tint an image, you can use CSS3 `background` to stack images and a `linear-gradient`. In the example below, I use a `linear-gradient` with no actual gradient. The browser treats gradients as images (I think it actually generates a bitmap and overlays it) and thus, is actually stacking multiple images.

```
background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(2,173,231,0.5), rgba(2,173,231,0.5)), url(images/mba-grid-5px-bg.png) repeat;
```

Will yield a graph-paper with light blue tint, if you had the png. Note that the stacking order might work in reverse to your mental model, with the first item being on top.

Excellent documentation by Mozilla, here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multiple_backgrounds

Tool for building the gradients:

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Note - doesn't work in IE11! I'll post an update when I find out why, since its supposed to.

Answer (score 31):

use

```
background:red url(../images/samle.jpg) no-repeat left top;
```

Answer (score 15):

And to add to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903659/why-i-cant-use-background-image-and-color-together/903665#903665) answer, make sure the image itself has a transparent background.

Comment: Good addition. This happened to me when I used a .jpg instead of a .png

Comment: Don't post this as na answer better as a comment.

Comment: Did you see from when this is?! Practically the founding generations. It was wild west, no rules. You newbies got it all served on a golden platter ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Actually there is a way you can use a background color with a background image. In this case, the background part will be filled with that specified color instead of a white/transparent one.

In order to achieve that, you need to set the `background` property like this:

```
.bg-image-with-color {
    background: url("example.png") no-repeat, #ff0000;
}
```

Note the comma and the color code after `no-repeat`; this sets the background color you wish.

I discovered this in [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bJ9NIGX4zRM), however I'm not affiliated with that channel or video in any means.

Comment: I doubted this, was surprised it works pretty well. Will need to look up the compatibility for it though.! +1

Comment: Nice! I built on this, for an even more complex example: `repeat 0/5px 5px linear-gradient(90deg,rgba(0,0,0,.05) 1px,transparent 0), repeat 0/5px 5px linear-gradient(180deg,rgba(0,0,0,.05) 1px,transparent 0), #eee` (this creates a repeating grid pattern; inspect this in the dev-tools "Styles" panel to see exactly what it is doing)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of using `background-image` and `background-color` together:

```css
.box {
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient( -45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2), rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 15px, transparent 15px, transparent 30px);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="background-color:orange"></div>
<div class="box" style="background-color:green"></div>
<div class="box" style="background-color:blue"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make half of the image transparent so the background colour is seen through it.

Else simply add another div taking up 50% up the container div and float it either left or right. Then apply either the image or the colour to it.

Comment: This assumes your background image was as big as the containing div.

Answer (score 0):

Gecko has a weird bug where setting the `background-color` for the `html` selector will cover up the `background-image` of the body element even though the `body` element *in effect* has a greater z-index and you *should* be able to see the body's `background-image` along with the `html` `background-color` based purely on simple logic.

**Gecko Bug**

Avoid the following...

```
html {background-color: #fff;}
body {background-image: url(example.png);}
```

**Work Around**

```
body {background-color: #fff; background-image: url(example.png);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello everyone I tried another way to combine background-image and background-color together:

HTML

```
<article><canvas id="color"></canvas></article>
```

CSS

```
article {
  height: 490px;
  background: url("Your IMAGE") no-repeat center cover;
  opacity:1;
} 

canvas{
  width: 100%; 
  height: 490px; 
  opacity: 0.9;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
window.onload = init();

var canvas, ctx;

function init(){
  canvas = document.getElementeById('color'); 
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); 
  ctx.save();  
  ctx.fillstyle = '#00833d'; 
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,490,490);ctx.restore();
}
```

Please let me know if it worked for you
Thanks

Answer (score -3):

```
background:url(directoryName/imageName.extention) bottom left no-repeat; 
background-color: red;
```

Comment: How/Why does this answer the question? Please elaborate by editing your answer.

Comment: Two lines like this are unnecessary. It can be put in one declaration. See other examples here on the page.


`background: red url(directoryName/imageName.extention) bottom left no-repeat;
`