# How do I combine a background-image and CSS3 gradient on the same element?

Tags: css, background-image, gradient

How do I use CSS3 gradients for my `background-color` and then apply a `background-image` to apply some sort of light transparent texture?

Comment: note: you can also position the background image(15px center) or set it's 'repeat' property this way (example works for Firefox 3.6+)
.some-class {background: url("../icon.png") no-repeat 15px center, -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #FFFFFF, #DDDDDD);}

Comment: [**SVG** or **SVG+CSS**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49108254) can be used to create flat textures (noise) or textured gradients, respectively.

Answer (score 1789, accepted):

Multiple backgrounds!

```css
body {
  background: #eb01a5;
  background-image: url("IMAGE_URL"); /* fallback */
  background-image: url("IMAGE_URL"), linear-gradient(#eb01a5, #d13531); /* W3C */
}
```

These 2 lines are the fallback for any browser that doesn't do gradients.
 See notes for stacking images only IE < 9 below.

- Line 1 sets a flat background color.
- Line 2 sets the background image fallback.

The final line sets a background image and gradient for browsers that can handle them.

- Line 3 is for all relatively modern browsers.

Nearly all current browsers have support for multiple background images and css backgrounds. See http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients for browser support. For a good post on why you don't need multiple browser prefixes, see http://codepen.io/thebabydino/full/pjxVWp/

**Layer Stack**

It should be noted that the first defined image will be topmost in the stack. In this case, the image is on TOP of the gradient.

For more information about background layering see http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#layering.

**Stacking images ONLY (no gradients in the declaration) For IE < 9**

IE9 and up can stack images this same way. You could use this to create a gradient image for ie9, though personally, I wouldn't. However to be noted when using only images, ie < 9 will ignore the fallback statement and not show any image. This does not happen when a gradient is included. To use a single fallback image in this case I suggest using Paul Irish's wonderful [Conditional HTML element](http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/) along with your fallback code:

```css
.lte9 #target{ background-image: url("IMAGE_URL"); }
```

**Background position, sizing etc.**

Other properties that would apply to a single image may also be comma separated. If only 1 value is supplied, that will be applied to all stacked images including the gradient. `background-size: 40px;` will constrain both the image and the gradient to 40px height and width. However using `background-size: 40px, cover;` will make the image 40px and the gradient will cover the element. To only apply a setting to one image, set the default for the other: `background-position: 50%, 0 0;` or for [browsers that support it](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-initial-value) use `initial`: `background-position: 50%, initial;`

You may also use the background shorthand, however this removes the fallback color and image.

```css
body{
    background: url("IMAGE_URL") no-repeat left top, linear-gradient(#eb01a5, #d13531);
}
```

The same applies to background-position, background-repeat, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, any ideas of how to then control the `background-position` just for the image and not the gradient?

Comment: thanks for this, excellent information. | @adardesign: use the background shorthand. Modifying the above example, it would be: background: url(IMAGE_URL) no-repeat left top, [appropriate-gradient];

Comment: If you're simply looking for a solution, stop here. For an explanation of how all this works, see my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681813/transparent-background-image-with-a-gradient).

Comment: @Gidgidonihan Gidgidonihan How can I use linear-gradient until image is loaded? Kindly suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 90):

If you also want to set ***background position*** for your image, than you can use this:

```css
background-color: #444; // fallback
background: url('PATH-TO-IMG') center center no-repeat; // fallback

background: url('PATH-TO-IMG') center center no-repeat, -moz-linear-gradient(top, @startColor, @endColor); // FF 3.6+
background: url('PATH-TO-IMG') center center no-repeat, -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(@startColor), to(@endColor)); // Safari 4+, Chrome 2+
background: url('PATH-TO-IMG') center center no-repeat, -webkit-linear-gradient(top, @startColor, @endColor); // Safari 5.1+, Chrome 10+
background: url('PATH-TO-IMG') center center no-repeat, -o-linear-gradient(top, @startColor, @endColor); // Opera 11.10
background: url('PATH-TO-IMG') center center no-repeat, linear-gradient(to bottom, @startColor, @endColor); // Standard, IE10
```

or you can also create a LESS mixin (bootstrap style):

```css
#gradient {
    .vertical-with-image(@startColor: #555, @endColor: #333, @image) {
        background-color: mix(@startColor, @endColor, 60%); // fallback
        background-image: @image; // fallback

        background: @image, -moz-linear-gradient(top, @startColor, @endColor); // FF 3.6+
        background: @image, -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(@startColor), to(@endColor)); // Safari 4+, Chrome 2+
        background: @image, -webkit-linear-gradient(top, @startColor, @endColor); // Safari 5.1+, Chrome 10+
        background: @image, -o-linear-gradient(top, @startColor, @endColor); // Opera 11.10
        background: @image, linear-gradient(to bottom, @startColor, @endColor); // Standard, IE10
    }
}
```

Answer (score 55):

One thing to realize is that the first defined background image is topmost in the stack. The last defined image will be bottommost. That means, to have a background gradient behind an image, you would need:

```css
  body {
    background-image: url("http://www.skrenta.com/images/stackoverflow.jpg"), linear-gradient(red, yellow);
    background-image: url("http://www.skrenta.com/images/stackoverflow.jpg"), -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(red), to(yellow));
    background-image: url("http://www.skrenta.com/images/stackoverflow.jpg"), -moz-linear-gradient(top, red, yellow);
  }
```

You could also define background positions and background size for the images.
I put together a blog post about some interesting things you can do with [CSS3 gradients](http://css3wizardry.com/2010/08/19/css3-gradients-and-patterns/)

Comment: Answer would be even better, when the W3C standards notation comes at the end.

Comment: This code does not seem to work properly mate. we can only see stackOverflow image, not the background image behind/ before it.

Comment: I think -webkit-gradient might be deprecated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10683364/gradient-not-working-in-chrome-but-works-in-firefox

Comment: The code may not work but this is a very important point. You can reorder how the background elements work but you have to think of them being layered. If you want the gradient on top of the image, put it first and you'll probably want to us RGBa so you can see the image behind: `background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(22,22,22,0), rgba(22,22,22,0.6)), url('image.jpg');`

Answer (score 51):

you could simply type :

```css
background: linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    rgba(0,0,0, 0),
    rgba(0,0,0, 100)
  ),url(../images/image.jpg);
```

Answer (score 26):

my solution:

```
background-image: url(IMAGE_URL); /* fallback */

background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.7) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.7) 100%), url(IMAGE_URL);
```

Answer (score 26):

I always use the following code to make it work. There are some notes:

1. If you place image URL before gradient, this image will be displayed **above** the gradient as expected.

```css
.background-gradient {
  background: url('http://trungk18.github.io/img/trungk18.png') no-repeat, -moz-linear-gradient(135deg, #6ec575 0, #3b8686 100%);
  background: url('http://trungk18.github.io/img/trungk18.png') no-repeat, -webkit-gradient(135deg, #6ec575 0, #3b8686 100%);
  background: url('http://trungk18.github.io/img/trungk18.png') no-repeat, -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #6ec575 0, #3b8686 100%);
  background: url('http://trungk18.github.io/img/trungk18.png') no-repeat, -o-linear-gradient(135deg, #6ec575 0, #3b8686 100%);
  background: url('http://trungk18.github.io/img/trungk18.png') no-repeat, -ms-linear-gradient(135deg, #6ec575 0, #3b8686 100%);
  background: url('http://trungk18.github.io/img/trungk18.png') no-repeat, linear-gradient(135deg, #6ec575 0, #3b8686 100%);
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="background-gradient"></div>
```

2. If you place gradient before image URL, this image will be displayed **under** the gradient.

```css
.background-gradient {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(135deg, #6ec575 0, #3b8686 100%), url('http://trungk18.github.io/img/trungk18.png') no-repeat;
  background: -webkit-gradient(135deg, #6ec575 0, #3b8686 100%), url('http://trungk18.github.io/img/trungk18.png') no-repeat;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #6ec575 0, #3b8686 100%), url('http://trungk18.github.io/img/trungk18.png') no-repeat;
  background: -o-linear-gradient(135deg, #6ec575 0, #3b8686 100%), url('http://trungk18.github.io/img/trungk18.png') no-repeat;
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(135deg, #6ec575 0, #3b8686 100%), url('http://trungk18.github.io/img/trungk18.png') no-repeat;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #6ec575 0, #3b8686 100%), url('http://trungk18.github.io/img/trungk18.png') no-repeat;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="background-gradient"></div>
```

This technique is just the same as we have multiple background images as describe [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_backgrounds.asp)

Answer (score 15):

I had an implementation where I needed to take this technique a step farther, and wanted to outline my work.  The below code does the same thing but uses SASS, Bourbon, and an image sprite.

```
    @mixin sprite($position){
        @include background(url('image.png') no-repeat ($position), linear-gradient(#color1, #color2));
    }
    a.button-1{
        @include sprite(0 0);
    }
    a.button-2{
       @include sprite (0 -20px);  
    }
    a.button-2{
       @include sprite (0 -40px);  
    }
```

SASS and Bourbon take care of the cross browser code, and now all I have to declare is the sprite position per button.  It is easy to extend this principal for the buttons active and hover states.

Answer (score 8):

### Use `background-blend-mode` and `rgba` to mix the background image and color

This is what you need:

```css
.myblendedbg {
  background-image: url("some_image.png");
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85); /* use rgba for fine adjustments */
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

If you adjust the **alpha value** of the `rgba` color value (it's at `.85` in the example), you can control the transparency.

Also, [`background-blend-mode`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-blend-mode.asp) has other values you can play with to get some really creative results.

**NOTE**: `background-blend-mode: color;` fails on Firefox, while `multiply` works on all modern browsers

Answer (score 5):

If you have strange errors with downloading background images use W3C Link checker: https://validator.w3.org/checklink

Here are modern mixins that I use (credits: [PSA: don't use gradient generators](http://codepen.io/thebabydino/full/pjxVWp/)):

```
.buttonAkc
{
    .gradientBackground(@imageName: 'accept.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-position: center right, top left !important;
}

.buttonAkc:hover
{
    .gradientBackgroundHover('accept.png');
}

.gradientBackground(@startColor: #fdfdfd, @endColor: #d9d9db, @imageName)
{
    background-color: mix(@startColor, @endColor, 60%); // fallback
    background-image: url("@{img-folder}/@{imageName}?v=@{version}"); // fallback
    background: url("@{img-folder}/@{imageName}?v=@{version}") no-repeat scroll right center, -webkit-linear-gradient(top, @startColor 0%, @endColor 100%) no-repeat scroll left top; // Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6
    background: url("@{img-folder}/@{imageName}?v=@{version}") no-repeat scroll right center, linear-gradient(to bottom, @startColor 0%, @endColor 100%) no-repeat scroll left top;
}

.gradientBackgroundHover(@imageName)
{
    .gradientBackground(#fdfdfd, #b5b6b9, @imageName);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want a gradient with a single background image in the center, you can do it with one line of code like this:

```
body {
  background:  url(logo.png) no-repeat fixed center center, linear-gradient(#00467f, #a5cc82) fixed;
}
```

Comment: But if the image is as big as the whole page, the image will get over the gradient.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a MIXIN that I created to handle everything that people might like to use:

```
.background-gradient-and-image (@fallback, @imgUrl, @background-position-x, @background-position-y, @startColor, @endColor) {
    background: @fallback;
    background: url(@imgUrl) @background-position-x @background-position-y no-repeat; /* fallback */
    background: url(@imgUrl) @background-position-x @background-position-y no-repeat, -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(@startColor) @background-position-x @background-position-y no-repeat, to(@endColor)); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
    background: url(@imgUrl) @background-position-x @background-position-y no-repeat, -webkit-linear-gradient(top, @startColor, @endColor); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
    background: url(@imgUrl) @background-position-x @background-position-y no-repeat,    -moz-linear-gradient(top, @startColor, @endColor); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: url(@imgUrl) @background-position-x @background-position-y no-repeat,     -ms-linear-gradient(top, @startColor, @endColor); /* IE10 */
    background: url(@imgUrl) @background-position-x @background-position-y no-repeat,      -o-linear-gradient(top, @startColor, @endColor); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: url(@imgUrl) @background-position-x @background-position-y no-repeat,         linear-gradient(top, @startColor, @endColor); /* W3C */
}
```

This can be used like so:

```
.background-gradient-and-image (#f3f3f3, "../images/backgrounds/community-background.jpg", left, top, #fafcfd, #f2f2f2);
```

Hope you guys find this helpful.

credit to @Gidgidonihah for finding the initial solution.

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to do the same thing. While background-color and background-image exist on separate layers within an object -- meaning they can co-exist -- CSS gradients seem to co-opt the background-image layer.

From what I can tell, border-image seems to have wider support than multiple backgrounds, so maybe that's an alternative approach.

http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/css3-border-images

UPDATE: A bit more research. Seems Petra Gregorova has something working here --> http://petragregorova.com/demos/css-gradient-and-bg-image-final.html

Answer (score 2):

You could use multiple background: linear-gradient(); calls, but try this:

If you want the images to be completely fused together where it doesn't look like the elements load separately due to separate HTTP requests then use this technique. Here we're loading two things on the same element that load simultaneously...

Just make sure you convert your pre-rendered 32-bit transparent png image/texture to base64 string first and use it within the background-image css call (in place of INSERTIMAGEBLOBHERE in this example).

I used this technique to fuse a wafer looking texture and other image data that's serialized with a standard rgba transparency / linear gradient css rule. Works better than layering multiple art and wasting HTTP requests which is bad for mobile. Everything is loaded client side with no file operation required, but does increase document byte size.

```
 div.imgDiv   {
      background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, white, rgba(255,255,255,0.95), rgba(255,255,255,0.95), rgba(255,255,255,0.9), rgba(255,255,255,0.9), rgba(255,255,255,0.85), rgba(255,255,255,0.8) );
      background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,INSERTIMAGEBLOBHERE");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolve the problem in that way. I define Gradient in HTML and background image in the Body

```css
html {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right top, color-stop(0.31, rgb(227, 227, 227)), color-stop(0.66, rgb(199, 199, 199)), color-stop(0.83, rgb(184, 184, 184)));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left bottom, rgb(227, 227, 227) 31%, rgb(199, 199, 199) 66%, rgb(184, 184, 184) 83%);
  height: 100%
}
body {
  background: url("http://www.skrenta.com/images/stackoverflow.jpg");
  height: 100%
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have to get gradients and background images working together in IE 9 (HTML 5 & HTML 4.01 Strict), add the following attribute declaration to your css class and it should do the trick:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0, startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#ff00ff'), progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='[IMAGE_URL]', sizingMethod='crop');
```

Notice that you use the `filter` attribute and that there are two instances of `progid:[val]` separated by a comma before you close the attribute value with a semicolon. Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ksevksev/Sebxy/). Also notice that when you look at the fiddle the gradient extends beyond the rounded corners. I don't have a fix for that other not using rounded corners. Also note that when using a relative path in the src [IMAGE_URL] attribute, the path is relative to the document page and not the css file (See [source](http://www.netvivs.com/how-to-fix-images-and-css-relative-path-in-alphaimageloader/)).

This article (http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/28/css3-solutions-for-internet-explorer/) is what lead me to this solution. It's pretty helpful for IE-specific CSS3.

Answer (score 1):

this is a background image with Gradient overlay, the **26%** is the opacity and **7deg** is the gradient position

[CSS Gradient Generator](https://cssgradient.io)

```
backgroundImage: `linear-gradient(7deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(39,17,68,1) 26%, rgba(10,19,20,0.49343487394957986) 100%), url('backgroundImg.jpeg')`,
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this to be the simplest solution. Kindly follow through.

```css
background: linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    rgba(0,0,0, 0),
    rgba(0,0,0, 100)
  ),url(../images/image.jpg);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to make span button with background image, background gradient combination.

http://enjoycss.com/ helped to do my work task. Only I have to remove some auto generated additional CSS. But it's really nice site build your scratch work.

```
#nav a.link-style span {
    background: url("../images/order-now-mobile.png"), -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(190,20,27,1) 0, rgba(224,97,102,1) 51%, rgba(226,0,0,1) 100%);
    background: url("../images/order-now-mobile.png"), -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(190,20,27,1) 0, rgba(224,97,102,1) 51%, rgba(226,0,0,1) 100%);
    background: url("../images/order-now-mobile.png"), linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(170,31,0,1) 0, rgba(214,18,26,1) 51%, rgba(170,31,0,1) 100%);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 3px solid #b30a11;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For my responsive design, my drop-box down-arrow on the right side of the box (vertical accordion), accepted percentage as position. Initially the down-arrow was "position: absolute; right: 13px;". With the 97% positioning it worked like charm as follows:

```
> background: #ffffff;
> background-image: url(PATH-TO-arrow_down.png); /*fall back - IE */
> background-position: 97% center; /*fall back - IE */
> background-repeat: no-repeat; /*fall back - IE */
> background-image: url(PATH-TO-arrow_down.png)  no-repeat  97%  center;  
> background: url(PATH-TO-arrow_down.png) no-repeat 97% center,  -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 1%, #eaeaea 100%); 
> background: url(PATH-TO-arrow_down.png) no-repeat 97% center,  -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(1%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#eaeaea)); 
> background: url(PATH-TO-arrow_down.png) no-repeat 97% center,  -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 1%,#eaeaea 100%); 
> background: url(PATH-TO-arrow_down.png) no-repeat 97% center,  -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 1%,#eaeaea 100%);<br />
> filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#eaeaea',GradientType=0 );
```

P.S.  Sorry, don't know how to handle the filters.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is cross-browser enough:

(modified base from [gradient editor](https://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#000000+0,000000+100&1+0,0+100) with black to transparent vertical gradient on top of image)

```
    background-image: url('YOURIMAGE.JPG');
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%),url('YOURIMAGE.JPG'); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%),url('YOURIMAGE.JPG'); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%),url('YOURIMAGE.JPG'); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#00000000',GradientType=1 ), progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='YOURIMAGE.JPG', sizingMethod='crop'); /* IE6-9 */
```

Answer (score -1):

As a sure method way, you can just make a background image that is say 500x5 pixels, in your `css` use:

```
background-img:url(bg.jpg) fixed repeat-x;
background:#<xxxxxx>;
```

Where `xxxxxx` corresponds with the color that matches the final gradient color.

You could also fix this to the bottom of the screen and have it match the initial gradient color.

Comment: -1 because: For one thing, "background-img" is not a valid CSS rule. For another, this doesn't actually answer the question.