# CSS: Creating textured backgrounds

Tags: css

I'm currently struggling with setting an image background for my site that will load fast enough.

I have used data url image and even optomized images but it's taking to long when loading the page since the `backgournd-image` is still very large.

Is it possible with CSS to create a textured background color like the one in the picture below?

**I tried and couldn't match this:**

[image]

Comment: Use a tiled background image, it's the only way to get something that detailed. Definitely *don't* use a `data:` URI. It looks like that particular pattern can be safely repeated at a pretty small size if you just change the texture a bit to be tileable.

Comment: You can easily [achieve this using SVG and CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49108254) in about 400 bytes. As a bonus, you can add a gradient for almost no extra cost.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

with latest CSS3 technology, it is possible to create textured background. Check this out: http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/#

but it still limited on so many aspect. And browser support is also not so ready.

your best bet is using small texture image and make repeat to that background. you could get some nice ready to use texture image here:

http://subtlepatterns.com

Comment: @albert, Nod 32 blocked  **patternify.com** and says The web page is on the list of websites with potentially dangerous content.

Comment: @stom huh...don't get malware warning when i go to it...who is Nod 32, and where is this list?

Comment: @albert , it seems the issue is with Nod 32 anti virus , it is showing false positive alert because some [spelling](https://forum.eset.com/topic/3875-reason-for-potentially-dangerous-content-warning/) in the website

Answer (score 30):

You should try slicing the image if possible into a smaller piece which could be repeated. I have sliced that image to a 101x101px image.

[image: BG Tile]

CSS:

```
body{
  background-image: url(SO_texture_bg.jpg);
  background-repeat:repeat;
}
```

But in some cases, we wouldn't be able to slice the image to a smaller one. In that case, I would use the whole image. But you could also use the CSS3 methods like what Mustafa Kamal had mentioned.

Wish you good luck.

Comment: Just curious, is there a reason you chose 101 pixels? It seems like a nonstandard size, and I'm wondering if there's a reason for this.

Comment: @ChristopherShroba, sorry for the late reply! Didn't saw your comment. I used 101px square size because when I inspected the image, I can see that the repeating portion in the image is a square box (5rows and 5cols). Our aim is to create a tile image, that looks perfectly blended. So I cropped that portion. And when tested using the background repeat, it looked okay! So always carefully look at the image, and try to figure out which portion can be cropped to create the perfect tiles. I don't think we should bother much about the "sizes". Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 5):

It's also possible to add texture **using only CSS** with [repeating-linear-gradient()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/repeating-linear-gradient)

**Try the following example:**

```css
div {
    margin:10px;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color: #67686b;
}

.pattern1{
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(36deg, rgba(255,255,255, 0.1), rgba(255,255,255, 0.1) 1px, transparent 0px, transparent 2px);
}

.pattern2 {
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255,255,255, 0.1), rgba(255,255,255, 0.1) 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 6px);
    background-size: 4px 4px;
}
```

```html
<section style='display:flex'>
  <div class='pattern1'></div>
  <div class='pattern2'></div>
</section>
```

**Bonus:** in this [link](https://codepen.io/bitmap/pen/AzowBq) you can find different types of patterns which you can customize to fit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

If you search for an image base-64 converter, you can embed some small image texture files as code into your `@import url('')` section of code.  It will look like a lot of code; but at least all your data is now stored locally - rather than having to call a separate resource to load the image.

**Example link**: http://www.base64-image.de/

When I take a file from my own inventory of a simple icon in PNG format, and convert it to base-64, it looks like this in my CSS:

```
url('data:image/png;base64,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')
```

With your texture images, you'll want to employ a similar process.

Answer (score 1):

Use an image editor to cut out a portion of the background, then apply CSS's background-repeat property to make the small image fill the area where it is used.

In some cases, background-repeat creates seams where the image repeats.  A solution is to use an image editor as follows: starting with the background image, copy the image, flip (mirror, not rotate) the copy left-to-right, and paste it to the right edge of the original, overlapping 1 pixel.  Crop to remove 1 pixel from the right edge of the combined image.  Now repeat for the vertical: copy the combined image, flip the copy top-to-bottom, paste it to the bottom of the combined, overlapping one pixel.  Crop to remove 1 pixel from the bottom.  The resulting image should be seam-free.