# Make CSS of Gradient from image style

Tags: css, gradient

Am trying to make `CSS` of gradient for following image
 [image]

just forget about the menu i need only the gradient since its little hard to get color code i tried this ..

```css
body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse, #2D84A7 5%, #0D354E);
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse, #2D84A7 5%, #0D354E);
  background: radial-gradient(center, ellipse, #2D84A7 5%, #0D354E);
}
```

can anyone help me to get above color and style

Comment: That's very interesting. Usually they do this using an image, but I'd like to see pure CSS solution.

Comment: @Shahar do you know any solution to get color code `rgb()` code from image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```css
body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(top left, ellipse, #917871 0%, #c7ac8f);
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(top left, ellipse, #917871 0%, #c7ac8f);
  background: radial-gradient(top left, ellipse, #917871 0%, #c7ac8f);
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.speckle {
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="speckle"></div>
```

**EDIT** Noise data URI borrowed from [Can you add noise to a CSS3 gradient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011113/can-you-add-noise-to-a-css3-gradient#answer-13996191).

Comment: I don't know that there's a way to reproduce the speckle effect using CSS, but I invite anyone who thinks they can to make their own answer extending from mine.

Comment: What do you mean "add pink"?

Comment: but back ground is clear i need something like doted am mean the spary effect

Comment: Again, there is no way I know of to reproduce the "dotted spray" effect, or as I said, "speckle", in CSS.

Comment: @lawrenceoverflow I added the speckle.

Comment: sorry bro i don't have enough reputation to make upvote thanks a lot

Comment: a small problem **if my screen height is `650px`** after `650px` it shows(creates) a new page effect **i want to make graident to be in fixed position even when scorling

Comment: sorry bro found solution for that `background-attachment: fixed;` this make fixed position

Answer (score 4):

## SVG Filters + CSS Gradients

You can create the following SVG image file (noise.svg) and reference it via `url()` or base64 encode the SVG data and put it directly in the stylesheet as a data URL.

```
<svg
  xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
  xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'
  width='300' height='300'>

    <filter id='n' x='0' y='0'>
            <feTurbulence
              type='fractalNoise'
              baseFrequency='0.8'
              stitchTiles='stitch'/>
    </filter>

    <rect width='300' height='300' fill='#b29080'/>
    <rect width='300' height='300' filter="url(#n)" opacity='0.8'/>
</svg>
```

Then in the stylesheet, overlay a linear gradient on the noise graphic to achieve the gradient displayed in your image.

```css
div {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background: linear-gradient(120deg, rgba(142,119,113,.8) 5%, rgba(255,219,183,.8) 35%), url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZwogIHhtbG5zPSdodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZycKICB4bWxuczp4bGluaz0naHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMTk5OS94bGluaycKICB3aWR0aD0nMzAwJyBoZWlnaHQ9JzMwMCc+CgoJPGZpbHRlciBpZD0nbicgeD0nMCcgeT0nMCc+CgkJPGZlVHVyYnVsZW5jZQoJCSAgdHlwZT0nZnJhY3RhbE5vaXNlJwoJCSAgYmFzZUZyZXF1ZW5jeT0nMC44NScKCQkgIHN0aXRjaFRpbGVzPSdzdGl0Y2gnLz4KCTwvZmlsdGVyPgoKCTxyZWN0IHdpZHRoPSczMDAnIGhlaWdodD0nMzAwJyBmaWxsPScjMDAwJy8+Cgk8cmVjdCB3aWR0aD0nMzAwJyBoZWlnaHQ9JzMwMCcgZmlsdGVyPSJ1cmwoI24pIiBvcGFjaXR5PScwLjcnLz4KPC9zdmc+Cg==');

  height: 350px;
  width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Comment: For a more details on using SVG images and CSS gradients to create backgrounds with textured gradients, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4011113/41906) for a similar question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :)

```
body, html {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      background: -webkit-radial-gradient(50% 60%, ellipse, #C9AE91 80%, #8F7872);
      background: -moz-radial-gradient(50% 60%, ellipse, #C9AE91 80%, #8F7872);
      background: radial-gradient(50% 60%, ellipse, #C9AE91 80%, #8F7872);
    }
```

Comment: open the image in Photoshop, then everything's easy :P