# How to Write on Sand With Css (text-shadow?)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make an effect with CSS so it will look like as it was written in the sand. Something like this:

[image: Image example]

I'm new to css and would like you to help me to achieve this if it's possible, of course. I tried this code:

```css
.text {
  color: #f0e2af;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), -1px -1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), 2px -4px 2px rgba(250, 250, 250, 1);
}
```

But it's not good at all :(

Of course, I don't want to use fonts and JS. Only CSS(I am not sure if it's possible).

Comment: Thank you for correcting me :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try like below code but, you should use a nicer font to look exactly like your image.You have to use a gradient background as per your style guide. Here i have used a plain background.

```css
.text {
  background:#f1e4b0; 
font-family: 'Atomic Age', cursive;
color:#f1e4b0; 
font-size:4em;
letter-spacing:0.05em;
text-transform: capitalize;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), -1px -1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), 2px -4px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
Love letters in the sand
</div>
```

Comment: Nice answer, take a look at mine's too!

Answer (score 0):

Using San's answer and [Can you add noise to a CSS3 gradient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011113/can-you-add-noise-to-a-css3-gradient), you could do this, where the basic difference is that this solution emulates the sand:

HTML:

```
<div class="text">Love letters in the sand</div>
```

CSS:

```
.text {
  background:#f1e4b0; 
  font-family: 'Atomic Age', cursive;
    color:#D3C9A2; 
  font-size:4em;
  letter-spacing:0.05em;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), -1px -1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), 1px -4px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
}
```

<kbd>[Live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gsamaras/ydf7ew6z/)</kbd>