# Replace navigation bar color with an image's

Tags: html, css, web

This is how navigation bar image looks like:

[image: Navigation Bar Image]

### Code Snippet

```css
main nav #wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #3a3a3a; }
  main nav #wrap .navbar {
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute; }
    main nav #wrap .navbar li {
      height: auto;
      width: 150px;
      float: left;
      text-align: center;
      list-style: none;
      font: normal bold 12px/1.2em Arial, Verdana, Helvetica;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      top: 20px;
      background: #3a3a3a; }
    main nav #wrap .navbar a {
      padding: 18px 0;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: white;
      display: block; }
    main nav #wrap .navbar li:hover, main nav #wrap .navbar a:hover {
      background-color: #54879d; }
    main nav #wrap .navbar li ul {
      display: none;
      height: auto;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0; }
    main nav #wrap .navbar li:hover ul {
      display: block; }
    main nav #wrap .navbar li ul li {
      background-color: #54879d; }
    main nav #wrap .navbar li ul li a {
      border-left: 1px solid #1f5065;
      border-right: 1px solid #1f5065;
      border-top: 1px solid #74a3b7;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #1f5065; }
```

```html
<main>
    <nav>
        <div id="wrap">
            <ul class="navbar">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Retrievals</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Data Listing</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Web Scheduling</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Google Maps Application</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Reporting</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" >Ad Hoc Report</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Drill Down Report</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Ranking Report</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Business Intelligence</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Business Dashboard</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Web Pivot Table</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Interactive Report</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">What-If Analysis</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Data Maintenance</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Database CRUD</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Database Update</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Order Entry</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Drag-and-Drop Application</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">B2B Portal</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">B2B Portal</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Secure Data-Driven Listings</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Secure Shopping Cart</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</main>
```

[image: nav bar picture]

I have this navigation bar and I am trying to replace that gray color with the one of the above attached image. As you can see, it is not a simple color. It has **small transparent dots**.

Is there anyway I can copy that color?

> PS: I do not want to use the image.

Comment: Your navigation background looks like a gradient. Maybe you might want to use one instead. [Gradient CSS Generator](http://www.cssmatic.com/gradient-generator) is a nice tool go grab your CSS for a custom gradient fast!

Comment: @AlexG where are you getting gradient from? The supplied image shows some faint noise, not a gradient. Which I guess is what the OP means by "small transparent dots". Also I might be wrong but I don't think noise is possible with pure css.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned on my comment, there's no css method for adding noise. However, you *can* embed images in html by `base64` encoding them. I've pinched the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011113/can-you-add-noise-to-a-css3-gradient), it's transparent so can be applied over any colour. If you need a different level/style of noise then you'll have to create it and `base64` encode it (a simple google search will bring plenty of options).

Anyway, hope this helps!

```css
main nav #wrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #3a3a3a;
    background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIAAAAyCAMAAAAp4XiDAAAAUVBMVEWFhYWDg4N3d3dtbW17e3t1dXWBgYGHh4d5eXlzc3OLi4ubm5uVlZWPj4+NjY19fX2JiYl/f39ra2uRkZGZmZlpaWmXl5dvb29xcXGTk5NnZ2c8TV1mAAAAG3RSTlNAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEAvEOwtAAAFVklEQVR4XpWWB67c2BUFb3g557T/hRo9/WUMZHlgr4Bg8Z4qQgQJlHI4A8SzFVrapvmTF9O7dmYRFZ60YiBhJRCgh1FYhiLAmdvX0CzTOpNE77ME0Zty/nWWzchDtiqrmQDeuv3powQ5ta2eN0FY0InkqDD73lT9c9lEzwUNqgFHs9VQce3TVClFCQrSTfOiYkVJQBmpbq2L6iZavPnAPcoU0dSw0SUTqz/GtrGuXfbyyBniKykOWQWGqwwMA7QiYAxi+IlPdqo+hYHnUt5ZPfnsHJyNiDtnpJyayNBkF6cWoYGAMY92U2hXHF/C1M8uP/ZtYdiuj26UdAdQQSXQErwSOMzt/XWRWAz5GuSBIkwG1H3FabJ2OsUOUhGC6tK4EMtJO0ttC6IBD3kM0ve0tJwMdSfjZo+EEISaeTr9P3wYrGjXqyC1krcKdhMpxEnt5JetoulscpyzhXN5FRpuPHvbeQaKxFAEB6EN+cYN6xD7RYGpXpNndMmZgM5Dcs3YSNFDHUo2LGfZuukSWyUYirJAdYbF3MfqEKmjM+I2EfhA94iG3L7uKrR+GdWD73ydlIB+6hgref1QTlmgmbM3/LeX5GI1Ux1RWpgxpLuZ2+I+IjzZ8wqE4nilvQdkUdfhzI5QDWy+kw5Wgg2pGpeEVeCCA7b85BO3F9DzxB3cdqvBzWcmzbyMiqhzuYqtHRVG2y4x+KOlnyqla8AoWWpuBoYRxzXrfKuILl6SfiWCbjxoZJUaCBj1CjH7GIaDbc9kqBY3W/Rgjda1iqQcOJu2WW+76pZC9QG7M00dffe9hNnseupFL53r8F7YHSwJWUKP2q+k7RdsxyOB11n0xtOvnW4irMMFNV4H0uqwS5ExsmP9AxbDTc9JwgneAT5vTiUSm1E7BSflSt3bfa1tv8Di3R8n3Af7MNWzs49hmauE2wP+ttrq+AsWpFG2awvsuOqbipWHgtuvuaAE+A1Z/7gC9hesnr+7wqCwG8c5yAg3AL1fm8T9AZtp/bbJGwl1pNrE7RuOX7PeMRUERVaPpEs+yqeoSmuOlokqw49pgomjLeh7icHNlG19yjs6XXOMedYm5xH2YxpV2tc0Ro2jJfxC50ApuxGob7lMsxfTbeUv07TyYxpeLucEH1gNd4IKH2LAg5TdVhlCafZvpskfncCfx8pOhJzd76bJWeYFnFciwcYfubRc12Ip/ppIhA1/mSZ/RxjFDrJC5xifFjJpY2Xl5zXdguFqYyTR1zSp1Y9p+tktDYYSNflcxI0iyO4TPBdlRcpeqjK/piF5bklq77VSEaA+z8qmJTFzIWiitbnzR794USKBUaT0NTEsVjZqLaFVqJoPN9ODG70IPbfBHKK+/q/AWR0tJzYHRULOa4MP+W/HfGadZUbfw177G7j/OGbIs8TahLyynl4X4RinF793Oz+BU0saXtUHrVBFT/DnA3ctNPoGbs4hRIjTok8i+algT1lTHi4SxFvONKNrgQFAq2/gFnWMXgwffgYMJpiKYkmW3tTg3ZQ9Jq+f8XN+A5eeUKHWvJWJ2sgJ1Sop+wwhqFVijqWaJhwtD8MNlSBeWNNWTa5Z5kPZw5+LbVT99wqTdx29lMUH4OIG/D86ruKEauBjvH5xy6um/Sfj7ei6UUVk4AIl3MyD4MSSTOFgSwsH/QJWaQ5as7ZcmgBZkzjjU1UrQ74ci1gWBCSGHtuV1H2mhSnO3Wp/3fEV5a+4wz//6qy8JxjZsmxxy5+4w9CDNJY09T072iKG0EnOS0arEYgXqYnXcYHwjTtUNAcMelOd4xpkoqiTYICWFq0JSiPfPDQdnt+4/wuqcXY47QILbgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==);
}
main nav #wrap .navbar {
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
main nav #wrap .navbar li {
    height: auto;
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    font: normal bold 12px/1.2em Arial, Verdana, Helvetica;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    top: 20px;
    background-color: #3a3a3a;
    background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIAAAAyCAMAAAAp4XiDAAAAUVBMVEWFhYWDg4N3d3dtbW17e3t1dXWBgYGHh4d5eXlzc3OLi4ubm5uVlZWPj4+NjY19fX2JiYl/f39ra2uRkZGZmZlpaWmXl5dvb29xcXGTk5NnZ2c8TV1mAAAAG3RSTlNAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEAvEOwtAAAFVklEQVR4XpWWB67c2BUFb3g557T/hRo9/WUMZHlgr4Bg8Z4qQgQJlHI4A8SzFVrapvmTF9O7dmYRFZ60YiBhJRCgh1FYhiLAmdvX0CzTOpNE77ME0Zty/nWWzchDtiqrmQDeuv3powQ5ta2eN0FY0InkqDD73lT9c9lEzwUNqgFHs9VQce3TVClFCQrSTfOiYkVJQBmpbq2L6iZavPnAPcoU0dSw0SUTqz/GtrGuXfbyyBniKykOWQWGqwwMA7QiYAxi+IlPdqo+hYHnUt5ZPfnsHJyNiDtnpJyayNBkF6cWoYGAMY92U2hXHF/C1M8uP/ZtYdiuj26UdAdQQSXQErwSOMzt/XWRWAz5GuSBIkwG1H3FabJ2OsUOUhGC6tK4EMtJO0ttC6IBD3kM0ve0tJwMdSfjZo+EEISaeTr9P3wYrGjXqyC1krcKdhMpxEnt5JetoulscpyzhXN5FRpuPHvbeQaKxFAEB6EN+cYN6xD7RYGpXpNndMmZgM5Dcs3YSNFDHUo2LGfZuukSWyUYirJAdYbF3MfqEKmjM+I2EfhA94iG3L7uKrR+GdWD73ydlIB+6hgref1QTlmgmbM3/LeX5GI1Ux1RWpgxpLuZ2+I+IjzZ8wqE4nilvQdkUdfhzI5QDWy+kw5Wgg2pGpeEVeCCA7b85BO3F9DzxB3cdqvBzWcmzbyMiqhzuYqtHRVG2y4x+KOlnyqla8AoWWpuBoYRxzXrfKuILl6SfiWCbjxoZJUaCBj1CjH7GIaDbc9kqBY3W/Rgjda1iqQcOJu2WW+76pZC9QG7M00dffe9hNnseupFL53r8F7YHSwJWUKP2q+k7RdsxyOB11n0xtOvnW4irMMFNV4H0uqwS5ExsmP9AxbDTc9JwgneAT5vTiUSm1E7BSflSt3bfa1tv8Di3R8n3Af7MNWzs49hmauE2wP+ttrq+AsWpFG2awvsuOqbipWHgtuvuaAE+A1Z/7gC9hesnr+7wqCwG8c5yAg3AL1fm8T9AZtp/bbJGwl1pNrE7RuOX7PeMRUERVaPpEs+yqeoSmuOlokqw49pgomjLeh7icHNlG19yjs6XXOMedYm5xH2YxpV2tc0Ro2jJfxC50ApuxGob7lMsxfTbeUv07TyYxpeLucEH1gNd4IKH2LAg5TdVhlCafZvpskfncCfx8pOhJzd76bJWeYFnFciwcYfubRc12Ip/ppIhA1/mSZ/RxjFDrJC5xifFjJpY2Xl5zXdguFqYyTR1zSp1Y9p+tktDYYSNflcxI0iyO4TPBdlRcpeqjK/piF5bklq77VSEaA+z8qmJTFzIWiitbnzR794USKBUaT0NTEsVjZqLaFVqJoPN9ODG70IPbfBHKK+/q/AWR0tJzYHRULOa4MP+W/HfGadZUbfw177G7j/OGbIs8TahLyynl4X4RinF793Oz+BU0saXtUHrVBFT/DnA3ctNPoGbs4hRIjTok8i+algT1lTHi4SxFvONKNrgQFAq2/gFnWMXgwffgYMJpiKYkmW3tTg3ZQ9Jq+f8XN+A5eeUKHWvJWJ2sgJ1Sop+wwhqFVijqWaJhwtD8MNlSBeWNNWTa5Z5kPZw5+LbVT99wqTdx29lMUH4OIG/D86ruKEauBjvH5xy6um/Sfj7ei6UUVk4AIl3MyD4MSSTOFgSwsH/QJWaQ5as7ZcmgBZkzjjU1UrQ74ci1gWBCSGHtuV1H2mhSnO3Wp/3fEV5a+4wz//6qy8JxjZsmxxy5+4w9CDNJY09T072iKG0EnOS0arEYgXqYnXcYHwjTtUNAcMelOd4xpkoqiTYICWFq0JSiPfPDQdnt+4/wuqcXY47QILbgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==);
}
main nav #wrap .navbar a {
    padding: 18px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    display: block;
}
main nav #wrap .navbar li:hover,
main nav #wrap .navbar a:hover {
    background-color: #54879d;
}
main nav #wrap .navbar li ul {
    display: none;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
main nav #wrap .navbar li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
main nav #wrap .navbar li ul li {
    background-color: #54879d;
}
main nav #wrap .navbar li ul li a {
    border-left: 1px solid #1f5065;
    border-right: 1px solid #1f5065;
    border-top: 1px solid #74a3b7;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #1f5065;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <nav>
        <div id="wrap">
            <ul class="navbar">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Retrievals</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Data Listing</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Web Scheduling</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Google Maps Application</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Reporting</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" >Ad Hoc Report</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Drill Down Report</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Ranking Report</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Business Intelligence</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Business Dashboard</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Web Pivot Table</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Interactive Report</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">What-If Analysis</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Data Maintenance</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Database CRUD</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Database Update</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Order Entry</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Drag-and-Drop Application</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">B2B Portal</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">B2B Portal</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Secure Data-Driven Listings</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Secure Shopping Cart</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</main>
```