# Transparent Background Image with a Gradient

Tags: image, background, css, gradient

Today I was designing a transparent PNG background that would only sit in the top left of a div, and the rest of the div would maintain a gradient background for all transparent areas of the PNG, and the rest of the div itself.

It might be better to explain through the code I thought might work:

```
#mydiv .isawesome { 
    /* Basic color for old browsers, and a small image that sits in the top left corner of the div */
    background: #B1B8BD url('../images/sidebar_angle.png') 0 0 no-repeat;

    /* The gradient I would like to have applied to the whole div, behind the PNG mentioned above */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ADB2B6 0%, #ABAEB3 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ADB2B6), color-stop(100%,#ABAEB3));
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ADB2B6', endColorstr='#ABAEB3',GradientType=0 );
}
```

What I've been finding is that most browsers pick one or the other - most choosing the gradient since its further down the CSS file.

I know some of the guys around here will say "just apply the gradient to the PNG you're making" - but thats not ideal because the div will maintain a dynamic height - sometimes being very short, sometimes being very tall. I know this gradient isn't *essential* but I thought it might be worth asking y'all what you thought.

**Is it possible to have a background image, while keeping the rest of the background as a gradient?**

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Keep in mind that a CSS gradient is actually an [image value](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#gradients), not a color value as some might expect. Therefore, it corresponds to `background-image` specifically, and not `background-color`, or the entire `background` shorthand.

Essentially, what you're really trying to do is layering *two* background images: a bitmap image over a gradient. To do this, you specify both of them in the same declaration, separating them using a comma. Specify the image first, followed by the gradient. If you specify a background color, that color will always be painted underneath the bottom-most image, which means a gradient will cover it just fine, and it will work even in the case of a fallback.

Because you're including vendor prefixes, you will need to do this once for every prefix, once for prefixless, and once for fallback (without the gradient). To avoid having to repeat the other values, use the longhand properties<sup>1</sup> instead of the `background` shorthand:

```css
#mydiv .isawesome { 
    background-color: #B1B8BD;
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    /* Fallback */
    background-image: url('../images/sidebar_angle.png');

    /* CSS gradients */
    background-image: url('../images/sidebar_angle.png'), 
                      -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ADB2B6 0%, #ABAEB3 100%);
    background-image: url('../images/sidebar_angle.png'), 
                      -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #ADB2B6), color-stop(100%, #ABAEB3));
    background-image: url('../images/sidebar_angle.png'), 
                      linear-gradient(to bottom, #ADB2B6, #ABAEB3);

    /* IE */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ADB2B6', endColorstr='#ABAEB3', GradientType=0);
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work correctly in IE as it uses `filter` for the gradient, which it always paints **over** the background.

To work around IE's issue you can place the `filter` and the background image in separate elements. That would obviate the power of CSS3 multiple backgrounds, though, since you can just do layering for all browsers, but that's a trade-off you'll have to make. If you don't need to support versions of IE that don't implement standardized CSS gradients, you have nothing to worry about.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Technically, the `background-position` and `background-repeat` declarations apply to both layers here because the gaps are filled in by repeating the values instead of clamped, but since `background-position` is its initial value and `background-repeat` doesn't matter for a gradient covering the entire element, it doesn't matter too much. The details of how layered background declarations are handled can be found [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#layering).</sub>

Comment: That makes sense, I didn't even think to count the gradient as a second background variable. Thanks for this!

Comment: Is it possible to define them in seperate classes?

ex:

.grayButton {
 define grdient here
}

.jobsButton {
 define background image here
}

Comment: @djschwartz: What do you mean?

Comment: Edited my original comment.  I want one css class to define the gradient and another css class to define the background image.

Comment: @djschwartz: Ah. If you want these to be layered over the same element with both classes, then it's not possible unfortunately :(

Comment: I was afraid that was the case, so for now I'll just use 2 div's so I can define them separately.  Thanks

Answer (score 38):

You can use [Transparency and gradients](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Images/Using_CSS_gradients). Gradients support transparency. You can use this, for example, when stacking multiple backgrounds, to create fading effects on background images.

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,0) 20%,
              rgba(255,255,255,1)), url(http://foo.com/image.jpg);
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, the generated background is not transparent. This will also fade to white, no matter what the elements look like underneath this element.

Answer (score 9):

The order of the image and gradient is very KEY here, i want to make that clear. The gradient/image combo works best like this...

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, top, rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(200,20,200,0.5)), url('../images/plus.png');
```

`background-image` will also work...

```
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, top, rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(200,20,200,0.5)), url('../images/plus.png');
```

the gradient needs to come first... to go on top. The absolute key here though is that the gradient uses **at least** 1 RGBA color... the color(s) need to be transparent to let the image come through. (`rgba(20,20,20,***0.5***)`). putting the gradient first in you css places the gradient on top of the image, so the lower the alpha setting on you RGBAs the more you see the image.

Now on the other hand if you use the reverse order the PNG needs to have transparent properties, just like the gradient, to let the gradient shine through. The image goes on top so your PNG needs to be saved as a 24 bit in photoshop with alpha areas... or a 32 bit in fireworks with alpha areas (or a gif i guess... barf), so you can see the gradient underneath. In this case the gradient can use HEX RGB or RGBA.

The key difference here is the look. The image will be much more vibrant when on top. When underneath you have the ability to tune the RGBA values in the browser to get the desired effect... instead of editing and saving back and forth from your image editing software.

Hope this helps, excuse my over simplification.

Comment: The first code example you've given results in an 'Invalid property value' when inspecting in Chrome

Comment: Thank you! I saw so many answers what it was to the other way (url first)  but it wasn’t working on safari on the iPhone for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using multiple background syntax:

```
.example3 {
    background-image: url(../images/plus.png), -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #cbe3ba,  #a6cc8b);
    background-image: url(../images/plus.png), -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#cbe3ba), to(#a6cc8b));
}
```

I read about this at [Here's One Solution](http://www.heresonesolution.com/2010/09/using-a-css-gradient-and-a-background-image-on-the-same-element/).

Answer (score 0):

***UPDATED***

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

.hero {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
position: relative;
}

.hero::before {
background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1566640269407-436c75fc9495?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80);
background-size: cover;
content: "";
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: -2;
opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero flex-center">
  <div class="hero-message">
    <h1 class="hero-title">Your text</h1>
    <h1 class="hero-sub-title">Your text2</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="not-hero flex-center bg-info">
    <div class="not-hero-message">
      <h1 class="hero-title">Your text</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
```

** It's working**

Answer (score -1):

Transparent images are not yet a CSS standard, yet they are supported by most modern browsers. However, this is part of the W3C CSS3 recommendation. Implementation varies from one client to another, so you will have to use more than one syntax for cross-browser compatibility.

http://www.handycss.com/effects/transparent-image-in-css/

Comment: The link is about CSS opacity on divs. It does not relate to transparent background images or gradients.