# Using background image along with css3 gradients

Tags: html, css

I'm unable to use background image along with the css3 gradient. I've gone through many solutions but i'm still unable to get the image.
[My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z2NCg/)

[Here's the image](http://img29.imageshack.us/img29/1194/messageicon.png)

Image used is transparent.I've tried adding background-image: url("img.png"), -webkit .. but this doesn't seem to work.Also tried having a div in below manner ..

```
<div id="div-with-gradient">
   <div id="div-with-image">
    <!-- content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Any solutions really appreciated..

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504071/is-it-possible-to-combine-a-background-image-and-css3-gradients

Comment: This is a duplicate question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681813/css3-transparent-background-image-and-gradient

Comment: apparently there has been much discussion about this! :-) Please search SO before you post a question.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to check this demo I did last week http://dabblet.com/gist/3106299

It uses an image and a CSS3 gradient on the same element.

---

Regarding your fiddle, `url('../img/msg_arrow.png')` won't work in jsFiddle - you need to specify the full path.

Also, you are overriding your style with

```
.btn1 {
    background-color: #f47e29;
    border: solid 1px #b16127;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f48c41', endColorstr='#d66f24',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
    padding: 0 26px;
}
```

which sets the solid orange background.

And another thing I've noticed just now: the use of `background-image` isn't right either:

```
background-image: url('../img/msg_arrow.png') scroll 0 0 no-repeat, linear-gradient(bottom, #000000, rgba(0,0,0,.12) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,.12) 49%, rgba(72,72,72,.12) 50%, rgba(247,245,245,.12));
```

You need to use `background` there instead of `background-image`.

Finally, one more thing to note is that backgrounds are displayed stacked one on top of another and **the last background listed is the one at the bottom** of the stack. In your case, it is the gradient that is displayed behind the semitransparent image. And since your gradient is made up of colours having a 0.12 fourth RGBa value (alpha), which is very low, it may be very difficult to spot behind another image, even when everything is working fine.