# Is it possible to append a CSS3 background with additional classes / styles?

Tags: css, background

Today I learned CSS3 supports [multiple backgrounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504071/is-it-possible-to-combine-a-background-image-and-css3-gradients), which is awesome.
What I'd really like is the ability to combine multiple backgrounds on the fly, EG:

```
.Watermarked{
  background: url('text/logo.png') bottom right no-repeat;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="Watermarked" 
     style="background:url('photos/very_pretty_sunset.jpg') 0 0 no-repeat;">
...
```

Somehow produces the computed style:

```
 background: url('text/logo.png') bottom right no-repeat,
             url('photos/very_pretty_sunset.jpg') 0 0 no-repeat;
```

Of course I can hard code the extra background style or add it using jquery.  I am seeking that sweet, pure, CSS-only solution.

***Answered***

Accepted thirtydot for the pure CSS answer- "You can't".

It's worth highlighting that if you're working with [SASS](http://sass-lang.com) (Rails 3.1, etc), the hard-coded styles are more palatable through variable use:

```
$watermarkImage: url('text/logo.png') left top no-repeat;
...
#very_pretty_sunset{
  background: $watermarkImage, url('photos/very_pretty_sunset.png') right bottom no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do that with CSS.

Whichever `background` is declared with higher [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity) will *completely* override the other one.

Comment: This is why I hate shorthand properties (which sometimes aren't even shorthand for everything).

Comment: @BoltClock - What does this have to do with shorthand properties?

Comment: Huge oversight in CSS language design

Answer (score 5):

Pseudo selectors :before or :after can be used to add a new background layer

```
/* This is your element that needs an additional background */
.myElement {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
/* This is your background layer */
.myElement:before {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: /* Define your bg */;
}
```

Comment: NB that the double colon `::before` is the new standard.

Answer (score 2):

**PREREQUISITE**

1. `width` of the div = width of the img - `border-image` img width
2. `height` of the div = height of the img - `border-image` img height
3. `border-image` img height = `border-bottom-width`
4. `border-image` img width = `border-right-width`
5. your border image must be transparent (obvious)

**CSS**

```
.Watermarked {
    -moz-border-image: url('text/logo.png') 0 100% 100% 0;
    -webkit-border-image: url('text/logo.png') 0 100% 100% 0;
    -o-border-image: url('text/logo.png') 0 100% 100% 0;
    border-image: url('text/logo.png') 0 100% 100% 0;
}
```

---

`box-sizing` alternative

---

**PREREQUISITE**

1. `border-bottom-width` = logo.png height
2. `border-right-width` = logo.png width
3. your border image must be transparent (optional)

**CSS**

```
.Watermarked {
    -moz-border-image: url('text/logo.png') 0 100% 100% 0;
    -webkit-border-image: url('text/logo.png') 0 100% 100% 0;
    -o-border-image: url('text/logo.png') 0 100% 100% 0;
    border-image: url('text/logo.png') 0 100% 100% 0;
   -moz-box-sizing:    border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing:        border-box;
}
```