# Background Images & Linear Gradients

Tags: css, background-image, background-color, linear-gradients

I have a div with a background image positioned on the top right and a background color for the remainder, is it possible to use a linear gradient instead of the color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, possible. You can use the following style definition:

```
background-image: url(/images/mybg.png) top right, linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999);
```

Also, see this post for a cross browser compatible solution.

Comment: Oops! Missed that out. I had copied the URL but forgot to paste it.. :) Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504071/is-it-possible-to-combine-a-background-image-and-css3-gradients

Comment: PS The multiple question marks may have made me look like I was mad, but I wasn't, they were necessary to add that post... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a gradient bitmap, cut a thin slice and use it as a background image.  Below I have a thin horizontal image than blends from left to right, it repeats vertically:

```
style="width: 110px; background-image: url(BlendLeft.ico);
                background-repeat: repeat-y;
```