# background gradient color and background image

Tags: html, css

I've defined this class which adds a gradient background colour:

```
.banner {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #75A319 0%, #9FCC1D 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 #9FCC1D;
}
```

I've also defined a class that adds a background image

```
.alertBell {
    background-image: url("../images/icons/bell.png");
    background-position: 5px 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left: 30px;
}
```

If I add both these classes to an element, it seems one overrides the other

```
<h2 class="banner alertBell"></h2>
```

Is there any way that I can have a background colour and a background image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use CSS3 multiple backgrounds, something like

```
.banner.alertBell {
    background-color:#9FCC1D;
    background-image:url("../images/icons/bell.png"),
        -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #75A319 0%, #9FCC1D 100%);
    background-repeat:no-repeat, repeat;
    background-position:5px 50%, 0 0;
}
```

[example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/57ymR/)

see also: [How do I combine a background-image and CSS3 gradient on the same element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504071/is-it-possible-to-combine-a-background-image-and-css3-gradients)

Answer (score 0):

The `Background` css property is actually a combination of `background-color`, `background-image`, `background-repeat`, `background-attachment` and `background-position` into one property.  Therefore when you set your H2's class property to `class="banner alertBell"`, alertBell class will overwrite any shared properties contained in the banner class.

You could try changing your banner class to:

```
.banner {
    background-color: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #75A319 0%, #9FCC1D 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 #9FCC1D;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
<div class="banner">
  <h2 class="alertBell"></h2>
</div>
```

Comment: AFAIK, you're not supposed to nest block elements like <h2> inside inline elements like <span>

Answer (score 0):

You're having that problem because CSS gradients are defined as `background-image`, not `background-color`.

So depending on which one is defined later in the CSS, the `background-image` will be either `.banner` or `.alertBell`