# Gradient not working in Chrome, but works in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-chrome

I'm trying to use the webkit gradient tag for Chrome, but it doesn't work at all. I've tried it in Firefox with the `background:-moz-linear-gradient(#000, #888);`, and it works just fine.

However with `background: -webkit-gradient(linear, from(#000), to(#888));` it doesn't work. Here's my bit of code:

```
   echo "<tr style='background:-moz-linear-gradient(#000, #888); background: -webkit-gradient(linear, from(#000), to(#888));'><td width='65'><img src='images/avatar/defaultuser.jpg' height='65' width='65'>";
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `-webkit-gradient` property is deprecated. Use the [new gradient syntax](http://www.webkit.org/blog/1424/css3-gradients/):

```
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#000, #888);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [colorzilla gradient generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) for crossbrowser gradients

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead :

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#000, #888);
```

`-webkit-gradient` was for Chrome v2 ...

Answer (score 1):

try

```
-webkit-linear-gradient(#000, #888);
```

Answer (score 1):

webkit needs something more:

where in firefox you write:

```
background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #d39637, #000000); /* Firefox 3.6+ */
```

in chrome you write:

```
background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#d39637), to(#000000));
```

Answer (score 1):

Webkit has its own syntax for gradients

```
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left bottom,
        left top,
        color-stop(0, rgba(0,0,0,1)),
        color-stop(1, rgba(136,136,136,1))
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Gradient color for chrome and Mozilla

background-image: -webkit-gradient(     linear,     left bottom,     left top,     color-stop(0.10, #72abe0),     color-stop(0.90, #eceaeb) );
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(     center bottom,     #72abe0 10%,        #eceaeb 90% );