# Background gradient + single background image

Tags: html, css

The background image is not appearing for the following CSS:

```
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fcfcfc,#cbcbcb);
    background-image: url("../images/new/account-dropdown.png") no-repeat 100%;
```

How would I correctly do the above?

Still have not received a correct answer that works...in the meantime I am using an additional `<img>` tag that is absolutely positioned over the gradient.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504071/is-it-possible-to-combine-a-background-image-and-css3-gradients

Comment: This provides a good answer, but does not account for the `no-repeat 100%` part, which I need.

Comment: Does: `background-image: url("../images/new/account-dropdown.png") no-repeat 100%, -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */` (from @Luca's link) not work?

Comment: No, that fails when I try it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
background-image: url("../images/new/account-dropdown.png");
background-size: 100%;
background-origin: content;
```

Comment: Nope, this 'works' insofar as the image appears correctly, but it kills the gradient.

Answer (score 0):

RichardTowers was close, but the gradient needs to be before the image:

```
 background-image:  -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999), url("../images/new/account-dropdown.png") no-repeat 100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try giving z-index property to display one background over the other.