# Styling SELECT (Option) tags with gradient and custom arrow

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, gradient

You can see my entire HTML here. You can copy/paste it into a demo document locally and see what I'm referring to.

http://chopapp.com/#ny9fxmtv

Basically I want to style the boxes to have both a gradient AND a custom arrow on the right. It's shown in the image above.

The problem is that the gradient I am getting is via this code:

`background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f8f8f8), to(#ececec)) ;`

This is line 21 in my code above. But because the "background" attribute is already taken up by this line, I cannot also include a "url(image.png)" tag to specify the custom down-arrow image, which is line 20 in my code.

Is there a way I can have gradient *and* a down-arrow image?

Thanks!

Comment: Not really an answer, but you mike like the Uniform jQuery plugin: http://uniformjs.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2504071/1577396

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this **[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2547064/1577396)**

```
background: #6cab26;
background: url(IMAGE_URL); /* fallback */
background: url(IMAGE_URL), -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#444444), to(#999999)); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
background: url(IMAGE_URL), -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
background: url(IMAGE_URL),    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999); /* FF3.6+ */
background: url(IMAGE_URL),     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999); /* IE10 */
background: url(IMAGE_URL),      -o-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: url(IMAGE_URL),         linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999); /* W3C */
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="selectParent">
 <select>
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>           
 </select>  
 </div>​


.selectParent{
width:80px;
overflow:hidden;
background: #d0e4f7;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #d0e4f7 0%, #73b1e7 24%, #0a77d5 50%, #539fe1 79%, #87bcea 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#d0e4f7), color-stop(24%,#73b1e7), color-stop(50%,#0a77d5), color-stop(79%,#539fe1), color-stop(100%,#87bcea));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #d0e4f7 0%,#73b1e7 24%,#0a77d5 50%,#539fe1 79%,#87bcea 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #d0e4f7 0%,#73b1e7 24%,#0a77d5 50%,#539fe1 79%,#87bcea 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #d0e4f7 0%,#73b1e7 24%,#0a77d5 50%,#539fe1 79%,#87bcea 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #d0e4f7 0%,#73b1e7 24%,#0a77d5 50%,#539fe1 79%,#87bcea 100%);



}

.selectParent select{
width: 100px;
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
border: none;
 background: transparent url("http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cc_mono_icon_set/blacks/16x16/br_down.png") no-repeat 60px center;


 }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/afshinprofe/qhCsJ/8/)

Comment: Thanks. I'd rather not add a div if possible, so I'll accept Mr_Green's answer (and the one in that other question, similar to this one) as the correct one. Much appreciate your solution though, it's a nice idea too!

Answer (score 0):

could you use a list in the boxes with

```
ul.className {list-style-image:url('someimage.gif');}
```

and then put your box background as you wish.

Second option is just to place a div in top of that div and have one with the gradient and the top one with the arrow. something like that?

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to do it with just background gradients. Looks like for < IE9, I do need all this jazz, but I won't bother. Many thanks!