# IE select drop down styling issue

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

I'm trying to change the color of a `select` element text.  It works for the all the browsers except IE (have not tried safari).

```
<div class="lang"> 
    <select id="language" class="selectOptionHeader">
        <option>sdafasd</option>
        <option>asdfas</option>
        <option>asdf</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

```css
#language {
    background: #DEDEDE -ms-linear-gradient(top , #2B3133, #000000) repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    color:#FFC31B;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
}
```

I know this is the right way because same code works in fiddle when I do it in IE.  But somehow it's not working in IE when it's implement in my page.

Any suggestions, solutions or hacks?

Comment: I would advise against this. Styling `select` elements is notoriously difficult due to its lack of support across different browsers - especially when using CSS3 effects such as a gradient. If you need to customise the style of a `select`, I would suggest using a plugin, such as Select2.

Comment: check if your version of IE supports gradient.

Comment: You can find your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/12690893/1817690

Comment: I answered your other (same) question hours ago. Please accept the answer as I tested I opera safari ff chrome and ie and it works in all

Comment: @Rachel...thanks.  Forgot about that

Answer (score 0):

IE, is the big problem after all, they still don't have compatibility with the style sheets, I'm just suggesting that you must to create a callback.css where store another css with the compatibility with the IE

this one won't work

```
background: #DEDEDE -ms-linear-gradient(top , #2B3133, #000000) repeat scroll 0% 0%;
```

but this one will work

```
background: #DEDEDE;
```

or use **background image** instead