# Flip background image on repeat-y in CSS

Tags: css

I have a gradient image as the background to my website and I am having problems making it look correct with all page sizes. The image is 291x1080 and I am having it do a repeat-x. This is fine with all pages that are no larger than 1080p. However, for a page with more content or a screen with a resolution larger than 1080p, a white space follows the background. I do not want to do a simple repeat-y because the gradient going from light to dark without a transition would be strange. Is there any way to flip the background image every time it does a repeat-y using CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the css to do this:

```css
body {
    ...
    background: #eeeeee url("/static/img/background.png") 0 0 repeat-x;
    ...
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is it isn't actually extending the texture, its just putting white(ish) space at the end.

Comment: There is no texture at the bottom of the image. At the bottom it is solid #eeeeee. Have a look: http://www.cyberexplo.it/static/img/background.png

Comment: I know, in my view, what he is trying to achieve is having the image repeat with out it looking odd. Your way is fine, but I'm not sure it's the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion: have the fabric texture and a gradient, not in an image.

For example:

```
body{
     background-image: url("/static/img/background.png") repeat, linear-gradient(top, #000000, #123456);
}
```

You should make sure you add the browser support tags (-webkit, etc)

For further reference check out this:
[How do I combine a background-image and CSS3 gradient on the same element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504071/is-it-possible-to-combine-a-background-image-and-css3-gradients)

Comment: It repeats, but it has that that problem where it goes from light to dark without a transition.

Comment: No, you need to remove the gradient from the fabric.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now. Still is effectively the same as the other answer except with more texture. I don't have the ability to remove the gradient though.

Comment: The texture looks identical to the iOS/Mac OSX Texture, really its up to you, but I think this method looks nicer.
http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_UdH8rcs3s1Q/TGdcZB6sO3I/AAAAAAAAAKU/KrPuD_wmBC4/s1600/iPadBackgroundTexture-grey.png