# How to combine Background Image and CSS Gradient

Tags: css, background-image

Not sure what I have going wrong here. The gradient is showing fine, but the image is not.

Page is located here (wordpress site):

http://philfaranda.staging.spatialmatch.com/

```
body {  
    background-color: #FFF !important; /* fallback color if gradients are not supported */
    background: #fff url(/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/body-bg2.png) repeat-x !important;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #A9A9A9) !important; /* For Chrome and Safari */
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #A9A9A9) !important; /* For old Fx (3.6 to 15) */
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #A9A9A9) !important; /* For pre-releases of IE 10 */
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #A9A9A9) !important; /* For old Opera (11.1 to 12.0) */
    background-image:         linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff, #A9A9A9) !important; /* Standard syntax; must be last */
}
```

EDIT: Also seems that the gradient effect isnt being displayed in IE, the image is...

Thanks in advance for any help,
Ken

Comment: your page is not available. a typo?

Comment: Loads fine for me in FF and IE

Comment: unnecessary wordpress tag here

Comment: Note that `!important` should be used as a last resort

Comment: Also very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504071/is-it-possible-to-combine-a-background-image-and-css3-gradients

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`background-image` ovverides `backgorund`. To make it properly work, there also need to be separatelly specified background-repeat. Tested in FF

```
body{
    background-color: #fcfcf0;
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-image: url(../img/abdul.jpg), -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #A9A9A9);
    /* And the same with other ugly prefixes */
    /* For older IE*/
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#A9A9A9');
}
```

After comments from Ken it seems that there will be problem with IE 9. It cannot deal with gradients and images.

Now, to make it work in IE, you should add gradients similar as above code snippet, than wrap your entire content in `div` for which you should add image css.

```
<body style="gradients styles...">
<div style="background-image styles">
Your content
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work, I changed each definition to be like your example. I think you missed a comma in your example though between the #A9A9A9) and the #fff url(.

Comment: Ah, sorry, it still need a bit modification, ill update in few minutes. The problem is with repeat.

Comment: Actually, Just noticed, neither gradient nor Image is being displayed in IE now :(

Comment: Got the gradient working, but no image still showing in IE, any suggestions?

Comment: It's working for me in IE9, I added this "filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#A9A9A9');"

Comment: True, with that filter gradient will work, but it is unusual MS solution that will not work combined with image. Filter will be drawn above image no mather what. Try adding margins to body and `background-image: url(../img/abdul.jpg);` to set image for IE and you will see gradient, and *below* (on margins area) that image.

Comment: I found this in a different thread "To work around IE's issue you can place the filter and the background image in separate layers. That would obviate the power of CSS3 multiple backgrounds, though, since you can just do layering for all browsers" 

Just not really understanding what to do.

Comment: What update? lol Not seeing anything new. I see where u are talking about adding margins, just not quite sure what exactly to do.

Comment: Added part with html `<body` etc. This way you can do so called *layering*