# css3 gradient and sprite at the same time

Tags: css, background-image

Now I found this already of SO, and everyone seems to think it works great [How do I combine a background-image and CSS3 gradient on the same element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504071/is-it-possible-to-combine-a-background-image-and-css3-gradients)

For some reason when I do it, it fails. The image works alone, and so does the gradient. What am I doing wrong?

```
.cSub {
  background: #00f;
  background-image: url("../images/header/Down_Arrow.svg") 9px 8px no-repeat, -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #0088b7 0%, #006da4 100%);
  background-image: url("../images/header/Down_Arrow.svg") 9px 8px no-repeat, -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #0088b7 0%, #006da4 100%);
  background-image: url("../images/header/Down_Arrow.svg") 9px 8px no-repeat, -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, #0088b7 0%, #006da4 100%);
  background-image: url("../images/header/Down_Arrow.svg") 9px 8px no-repeat, -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, #0088b7 0%, #006da4 100%);
  background-image: url("../images/header/Down_Arrow.svg") 9px 8px no-repeat, linear-gradient(135deg, #0088b7 0%, #006da4 100%);
  border-top: 2px solid #0089b7;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `background-image` as the property but you put all the background value for it, just put `background` instead of `background-image`.

Comment: Damn, I must be tired. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

```
.cSub {    
  background: #00f;    
  background: url("../images/header/Down_Arrow.svg") 9px 8px no-repeat, -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #0088b7 0%, #006da4 100%);    
  background: url("../images/header/Down_Arrow.svg") 9px 8px no-repeat, -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #0088b7 0%, #006da4 100%);    
  background: url("../images/header/Down_Arrow.svg") 9px 8px no-repeat, -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, #0088b7 0%, #006da4 100%);   
  background: url("../images/header/Down_Arrow.svg") 9px 8px no-repeat, -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, #0088b7 0%, #006da4 100%);    
  background: url("../images/header/Down_Arrow.svg") 9px 8px no-repeat, linear-gradient(135deg, #0088b7 0%, #006da4 100%);   
  border-top: 2px solid #0089b7;    
width:200px;    
height:auto    
}
```

you need to mentiion width and the height to get display the background.