# Transparent image pattern over color in CSS

Tags: html, css, image, design-patterns, overlay

I'm trying to add a simple .png pattern over a color gradient in CSS. Here is the markup:

HTML:

```
<div class="pattern">
  <div class="widget_heading">
    <h4>Feed</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.pattern {
 background: url(../img/leatherpattern.png) repeat;
 }

.widget_heading { 
  display:block; border:1px solid #3F943A; height:40px; border-top-left-radius: 5px  5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5% 0%;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px; background: #3c8522; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #3c8522 0%, #599d40 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#3c8522), color-stop(100%,#599d40)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #3c8522 0%,#599d40 100%); 
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #3c8522 0%,#599d40 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #3c8522 0%,#599d40 100%); /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #3c8522 0%,#599d40 100%); /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#3c8522', endColorstr='#599d40',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
  }
```

I have no idea why it's not showing up overtop, but it is showing up. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/j4JjW/3/

Comment: a simpler one works http://jsfiddle.net/btevfik/j4JjW/4/

Comment: looks like you can't have gradient and background picture at the same time

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504071/is-it-possible-to-combine-a-background-image-and-css3-gradients

Comment: Thanks btevfik, that link worked!

Answer (score 0):

Both your gradients and your image are not at all transparent, so it is not possible to see both when they are taking up the same space. [As you can see here](http://jsfiddle.net/j4JjW/5/) the gradient just covers up the image, and the same would be true in the reverse. You need to give one of the two some transparency `(and put it on top)`.