# How do I overlay a gradient background over an existing background with CSS?

Tags: css

I am trying to overlay a white-black linear gradient to an existing image. I have it set up like below; however, only the gradient layer is showing. Can someone point out where I went wrong?

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6nJJD/

HTML

```
<div>hello</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%, #000000 100%), url("http://us.123rf.com/400wm/400/400/adroach/adroach1210/adroach121000001/15602757-flower-and-bird-ornaments-retro-tile-repeat-as-many-times-as-you-like.jpg") repeat #eae7de;
    color:#544a46;
    font:62.5%/1.6 Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif;
    height:500px;
    width:500px
}
```

Comment: Dublicate Question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504071/is-it-possible-to-combine-a-background-image-and-css3-gradients

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try to change your gradient colours using [RGBA](http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/) values

```
background: 
   linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255, 0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0, 1) 100%),
   url(...);
```

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/J7bUd/

Try also changing `rgba(255,255,255, 0)` with `transparent`: the result is slightly different but probably it's exactly what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this using RGBA in the gradient.

http://jsfiddle.net/6nJJD/3/

CSS:

```
linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%)
```

You can modify the "0.65" value to attain the desired transparancy.

> For Creating More Gradients as you like you can visit [Ultimate Css
>   Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

Hope This HElps

Answer (score 0):

like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/6nJJD/2/

```
 linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 0%, #000000 100%)
```