# CSS3 Navigation bar (responsive) or traditional background image

Tags: css, background-image, html

is it possible to create the following shape using pure CSS3 - in a single layer i.e.

```
<div class="nav-bg">...</div>
```

[image: UI Design]

I'm currently using the traditional slice the curve apart and add it as a bg-image. I'm just curious and i couldn't find anything on the internet about a CSS only method of creating this.

I also gave this a shot, [How do I combine a background-image and CSS3 gradient on the same element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504071/is-it-possible-to-combine-a-background-image-and-css3-gradients), no bueno.

Comment: That should be possible with `:before` and `:after`.

Comment: why wont you just use an image?

Comment: @areeb-siddiqui - I'm using an image right now, current markup is `<div class="nav-bg"><span class="curve-center"></span><ul class="menu">...</ul></div>` and the respective CSS. As stated in my question "for science" I would like to know if its possible w/o an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html) may help you in creating curve lines and straight lines and many other things w/o using an image.