# Adding a search icon in my text box

Tags: css

What I'm trying to do: Add the search icon in the right of the textbox

[image]

The code im using in [css] is this:

```
.tb4 {
background: #3f4c6b; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #3f4c6b 0%, #3f4c6b 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#3f4c6b), color-stop(100%,#3f4c6b)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #3f4c6b 0%,#3f4c6b 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #3f4c6b 0%,#3f4c6b 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #3f4c6b 0%,#3f4c6b 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #3f4c6b 0%,#3f4c6b 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#3f4c6b', endColorstr='#3f4c6b',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
 background: url(web.png) top right no-repeat;
 padding: 4px 4px 4px 22px;
 height: 18px;
 border: 1px solid #494949;
}
```

The result I get is :

[image]

- I do have web.png in my main folder. *

Comment: @r043v that set the gradient but the search icon still didnt appear

Comment: can you make a fiddle ? the way css is written, only web.png is suppose to show

Answer (score 0):

```
background: url(web.png) top right no-repeat;
```

This is over-ruling the other `background` settings. You've tried `background-image` but I suspect that this conflicts with the gradient settings, which are *effectively* using an image-property of the background.

**Added**: This [SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504071/is-it-possible-to-combine-a-background-image-and-css3-gradients) indicates that it is possible to combine gradients with an image.

I would add the button immediately after the search box, and use positioning, perhaps a negative left-margin, to bring it back over the textbox. If the textbox is an `input` element then I would probably use the image as a background to a `label`, and bring this label back across to the left, perhaps with a `z-index` to place it above the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

The gradients and the background image are going to conflict. Try:

```
.tb4 {
  /* as above but without the background line for web.png */
  position: relative; /* and add this line */
}
.tb4:after { /* and this rule */
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 20px; /* change dimensions as needed to match image */
  height: 20px;
  background: url(web.png) top right no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Will the icon still be clickable (separately from the textbox) if you use :after?

Comment: Hmm, it depends, but I would hazard a guess not for your purposes. Can you post the html around and including the searchbox? Also if you could confirm if you can add/change that html. -- edit -- Sorry, thought you were OP. If :after (or :before) is used with an anchor/link tag then it is considered part of the clickable link space, but I don't think you can bind JS events to it for example. So it depends what the OP needs and what the html is as to whether it matters.

Answer (score 0):

the right way to right  this would be :

```
background: #3f4c6b url(web.png) top right no-repeat;/* Old browsers */
background: url(web.png) top right no-repeat,-moz-linear-gradient(top,  #3f4c6b 0%, #3f4c6b 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: url(web.png) top right no-repeat, -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#3f4c6b), color-stop(100%,#3f4c6b)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: url(web.png) top right no-repeat, -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #3f4c6b 0%,#3f4c6b 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: url(web.png) top right no-repeat ,-o-linear-gradient(top,  #3f4c6b 0%,#3f4c6b 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: url(web.png) top right no-repeat ,-ms-linear-gradient(top,  #3f4c6b 0%,#3f4c6b 100%); /* IE10+ */
background:url(web.png) top right no-repeat , linear-gradient(to bottom,  #3f4c6b 0%,#3f4c6b 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#3f4c6b', endColorstr='#3f4c6b',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

So image can sit on top of gradient.
Are `top right` the good coordinates to give ?