# Combine background-colour CSS3 with a image semitransparent

Tags: html, image, css

How can i combine a background-image with a degraded background-color in CSS3?

The css code:

```
background: linear-gradient(rgb(208, 208, 208), rgb(242, 242, 242) 50%, rgb(208, 208, 208)) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgb(51, 51, 51);
border: 1px solid rgb(239, 241, 239);
position: relative;
```

And the image is this:

```
http://d227xyj983n2jj.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/scoring.png
```

That image is a example. I know that this effect degraded with the image combine is a great effect... But i don't know combine it... Help!

Answer (score -1):

You can combine gradients and images in a background see:
[How do I combine a background-image and CSS3 gradient on the same element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504071/is-it-possible-to-combine-a-background-image-and-css3-gradients)

For the added transparency you can simply use [rgba()](http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/) rather than rgb() like so:

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/wEgUQ/1/)**

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
div {
  background: url("http://d227xyj983n2jj.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/scoring.png") repeat scroll 0% 0%, -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(208, 208, 208, 0.5), rgba(242, 242, 242, 0.5) 50%, rgba(208, 208, 208, 0.5));
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border: 1px solid rgb(239, 241, 239);
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```