# How define image in HTML tag for more styles?

Tags: html, css

So, I'm using something like this in my CSS:

```
li {
    background-image: url('example.png');
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.15)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0.15))), url('avatar.png');
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 100%), url('avatar.png');
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 100%), url('avatar.png');
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 100%), url('avatar.png');
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 100%), url('avatar.png');
    background-image:         linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 100%) 100%), url('avatar.png');
}
```

But in each `<li>` will be a different image.

Comment: Use `<img>` for avatars, not background. (original post had `avatar.png`)

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504071/is-it-possible-to-combine-a-background-image-and-css3-gradients

Comment: @WesleyMurch http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23770361/revisions yes, but like the description below the code said, he'd use something other than `avatar.png`, so the filename was more like a placeholder, hence why I changed it to a more generic name in my cleanup edit.

Comment: @Joeytje50 I think he just wants to use a different avatar for each user or whatever, but you may be right.

Comment: @Edoras is this right: you want to insert a different image in each of these `<li>`s, but you *also* want to give them a gradient background behind that image? Is that right?

Comment: @Joeytje50 Yeah, you're right, actually I'm using this in `li:before`

Comment: If you want each `<li>` to have a different `background-image`, you'll need to apply more classes to your stylesheet, or use ID's to target each li. Here's a fiddle using `nth-of-type` selection and single background images: http://jsfiddle.net/h8YH7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using either the `::before` or `::after` pseudo-element. For example:

```
li:before {
    content: url('example.png');
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.15)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0.15))), url('avatar.png');
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 100%), url('avatar.png');
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 100%), url('avatar.png');
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 100%), url('avatar.png');
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 100%), url('avatar.png');
    background-image:         linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 100%) 100%), url('avatar.png');
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/58gCM/).

Then, instead of specifying a background image, of which the rule will be overridden by the latter gradient styles, you'll be specifying a separate style, so it will show both of these.

Comment: Yeah, Im using this how I sad, but how can I cange just image url from HTML? because each `<li>` in html will be one message in chat body, and in `li:before` is avatar of each user.

Comment: @Edoras Yes you can, but you'd have to use the `<img>` tag instead. Just use `<li><img src="example.png"/></li>` then instead.

Comment: Yeah, ok, so I will use `<img>` tag.

Comment: Just one more question, how apply gradient on `<img>` tag?

Comment: simply apply these styles to `img` instead of `li`. The image would have to have a transparent background for that though.

Comment: I tried, but I think it showed in the background behind the picture in `<img>` tag, its possible show it in front of image when the image is not transparent?

Comment: Would it work for you to use `box-shadow:inset 0px -20px 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);`?