# image not fit the screen

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

In my ruby on rails web application, I have an Image that consists of two colours the first portion is black and the second portion is blue. When I set this image on the background, the image is repeating:

```
body {
    background:url("bg.png");
}
```

but when I use below the repeatation of the image is remove:

```
body {
    background:url("bg.png") 0 0 repeat-x;
}
```

but vertically its not fit to the screen,

[image]

it covers the 2/3rd portion of the screen. and the black portion is fit but the blue portion not cover the remaining screen and I want to increase only the blue portion of the image not black, is it possible.

Kindly suggest me, waiting for your reply.
Thanks.

Comment: You can't repeat half an image on a single element.

Comment: then what I do to resolve this issue.

Comment: is there any way to repeat on the blue portion of the image.

Comment: make a new image in which your blue portion is way too large so that it goes to the end of the page. There is no other way you can handle this

Comment: Or just use two backgrounds, for two different elements, especially if the black will be a background for the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Different Elements**

Using background images is an art

I would recommend using two elements - a "nav" element & then set the background of the `body` to the blue gradient. You can use the [`background-size: cover`](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) property to make this work:

http://jsfiddle.net/wM2B7/

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss
body {
    background: url("gradient.png");
    background-size: cover;
}

nav {
    height: 45px;
    display: block;
    background: url("black.png") 0 0 repeat-x;
}
```

This will allow you to give the illusion of having a single background image, whilst maintaining the flexibility of having multiple elements (I.E the `body` styling will act for the body, the `nav` styling will act for the `nav`)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use CSS3 gradient together with a background image. See this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504071/is-it-possible-to-combine-a-background-image-and-css3-gradients) for details.

Create a background image that is just the black part and then use the CSS gradient to create the blue part.