# Applying gradient over background cover image

Tags: html, css, gradient

I have the following [fiddle with background image](http://jsfiddle.net/2gses/2/) which I am using as cover (trying to find the best fit without distorting the image).

Right now I want to add gradient on top of this image and also I see a similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2547064/1090562) I can not make it work ( gradient [does not show up](http://jsfiddle.net/2gses/3/) ).

Is there a way to have:

```
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
background-image: url(pathToImg);
```

together with gradient?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504071/is-it-possible-to-combine-a-background-image-and-css3-gradients

Comment: @NikTerentyev have you read the question? I already showed that I looked into this question and tried to apply it's solution. I also showed that result does not work for me. So I can not understand what you link suppose to mean.

Comment: you have to place the gradient background (specified by `linear-gradient`) ***before*** the image background (specified by `url`), http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/2gses/4/ However the gradient background cover the image, there is not any partial transparency here because you don't use transparent colors for the color stops.

Comment: have you read my comment ***carefully***? I said that your colors are solid color (colors which don't have alpha channel).

Comment: Background colours, and therefore gradients, are placed beneath background images, so you won't see the gradient as you have constructed your fiddle. You could try applying the gradient to your element's ::after pseudo element. I'm on my phone right now, but I'll check in tomorrow if some intrepid SO'er hasn't already answered.

Comment: @KingKing Most probably you edited you comment after I read it and replied. Right now I reread it. Thanks.

Comment: @ChrisHardie the problem is that he does not know how to place the gradient on top (he of course knows that the gradient is under the image in his demo), it's the problem of understanding the syntax of specifying multiple-backgrounds (the first specified will be laid on top of the following ones specified).

Comment: thank you @ChrisHardie and KingKing. Because of your comments I found a way to do what I wanted. I will add the answer in few seconds.

Comment: continue to king king something like this http://jsfiddle.net/2gses/5/

Comment: @marathonman this is exactly what I came up with.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you KingKing and Chris Hardie. Thanks to your comments I understood what I was doing wrong and how to fix it.

So the first problem is that my url-image was on top of my gradient, thus hiding it (thanks kingKing). The second problem is that I need gradient to be transparent (thanks Chris).

So here is a [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/2gses/5/).

If somebody will give me a better answer, I would be happy to accept it.

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,1)), url(imga.jpg);
```