# Radial-gradient over a background image does not work on Safari

Tags: css, safari, cross-browser

I'm trying to add a radial gradient over a background image. It works perfectly on Chrome and Firefox, but it does not on Safari. I can't figure out why.

Here is my css :

```
   #banner {
        background-attachment: scroll, scroll, scroll, fixed;
        background-color: #fff;
        background: radial-gradient(circle at 60% 30%, rgba(0,0,0,0.1), rgba(0,0,0,0.7)),url(../images/fond2.jpg) center left no-repeat;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        }
```

I tried using :

```
       background : -webkit-radial-gradient(circle at 60% 30%, rgba(0,0,0,0.1), rgba(0,0,0,0.7)),url(../images/fond2.jpg) center left no-repeat;
```

But it still does not work. Any idea on how I could fix that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS

```
 #banner {
    background-attachment: scroll, scroll, scroll, fixed;
    background-color: #fff;
  /* Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
   background:-webkit-radial-gradient(60% 30%, closest-side,rgba(0,0,0,0.1),              rgba(0,0,0,0.7)); 
  /* For Opera 11.6 to 12.0 */
  background:-o-radial-gradient(60% 30%, closest-side,rgba(0,0,0,0.1), rgba(0,0,0,0.7));
  /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
   background:-moz-radial-gradient(60% 30%%, closest-side,rgba(0,0,0,0.1), rgba(0,0,0,0.7));
  /* Standard syntax */
   background:radial-gradient(60% 30%, closest-side,rgba(0,0,0,0.1), rgba(0,0,0,0.7));
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    }
```

You can also check: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp or [How do I combine a background-image and CSS3 gradient on the same element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504071/is-it-possible-to-combine-a-background-image-and-css3-gradients)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it turns out the problem comes from the 'circle'. For old version of Safari I had to use.

```
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(top center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,0.1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.7) 90%), url(../images/fond2.jpg) center left no-repeat;
```

It's not exactly the same effect, but it is a good fallback.

Hope it helps !