# Using background image over gradient

Tags: css, background-image, gradient

What I am trying to achieve is that I have gradient on the div background, and I am trying to add a background image over the gradient(image is just a pattern) but either only gradient is being applied or only the pattern, not both
I get a white background with this code:

```
 #box{
    padding:50px;
    background:linear-gradient(45deg, #A50F06 0%, #51A351 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent url('bs-docs-masthead-pattern.png') repeat scroll center center transparent;
    }
```

only gradient with this:

```
#box{
background:linear-gradient(45deg, #A50F06 0%, #51A351 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% 
}
 #box:after{
 background: transparent url('pattern.png') repeat scroll center center transparent;
}
```

what m I doing wrong?

Comment: Multiple background images, need to be comma separated and the stacking order is important. - http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/multiple-backgrounds-syntax/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I combine a background-image and CSS3 gradient on the same element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504071/how-do-i-combine-a-background-image-and-css3-gradient-on-the-same-element)

Answer (score 0):

Update your CSS like below.

```
 #box{
  background:url('https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSXwTmM2R_vmBHFpn720_8bGOaegnP5Kawh0wb4JggN5rUALGwGvw') no-repeat center center, linear-gradient(45deg, #A50F06 0%, #51A351 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0%;
  height:500px;
   }
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/m5cpsjxs/1/)

Answer (score 0):

add `content:""` in pseudo element

```css
* {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    html,
    body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    #box {
      background: linear-gradient(45deg, #A50F06 0%, #51A351 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0%;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    #box::after {
      content: "";
      background: url('http://s28.postimg.org/rfznph7ul/pattern.png');
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      display: block;
    }
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

Comment: Nope it's not working... Here's the link to my image, can you please give it a shot (It's really bugging me now), also the thing you said about adding `content:""` why do we need to do this? Link:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/iexuzlqujo5bnlb/pattern.png?dl=0

Comment: updated the snippet you image is working please check my answer @azazelroman

Comment: Yes it is working :) just one quick question can this be done without styling the `html and body`? I mean i only have to apply on the div so... actually i am using bootstrap framework and adding style to body might mess up.

Comment: i have just added it so the div takes full height :) there is no need if you are using a framework

Comment: without styles for `body` and `html` [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/kvoygcas/1/)