# Background image with both linear gradient and image not working (using Wordpress)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, less

Here is code:

```
style="background-image: linear-gradient(151deg,#6a7a8f 9%,#8692A4 30%,#a9b1be 49%, #ced2d9 66%, #f1f0f1 88%),url(<?php echo $page['image']; ?>);"
```

It is on the div, for some reason the linear gradient is the only things that appears. When I put the url() in front of the linear-gradient, then the image is the only that appears.

I checked out the other stackoverflow questions that are pretty similar, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Can you show us the resulting HTML rendered by WordPress?  (ie: View-source in your browser, as opposed to what you're editing in the WordPress editor.)  Additionally, could you isolate it to a jsfiddle?  According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504071/is-it-possible-to-combine-a-background-image-and-css3-gradients, it looks fine.

Answer (score 2):

You are using solid colors (HEX), so they cover your image. You must to use **RGBA** colors.

Like this:

```
style="background-image: linear-gradient(151deg,rgba(106,122,143,0.5) 9%,rgba(134,146,164,0.5) 30%,rgba(169,177,190,0.5) 49%, rgba(206,210,217,0.5) 66%, rgba(241,240,241,0.5) 88%),url(<?php echo $page['image']; ?>);"
```

Comment: This is true - in a way.  But if you should clarify - putting the url() part first, you'd have the image over the top of the gradient.

Comment: Not sure what the OP is wanting, asked for clarification on what's rendered vs. what's being edited in WP.