# Gradient CSS with Background IMG

Tags: html, css, gradient

so im trying to figure out how to get IMG have a gradient layer on top of it, and it is not showing up correctly!

It either shows gradient or shows image, but not both at the same time.

CSS im using

```
#grad1 {
height: 200px;
background: url(images/back3.gif), rgba(255,0,0,1)); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
background: url(images/back3.gif), -o-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255,0,0,0), rgba(255,0,0,1)); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
background: url(images/back3.gif), -moz-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255,0,0,0), rgba(255,0,0,1)); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
background: url(images/back3.gif), linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,0,0,0), rgba(255,0,0,1)); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
```

}

html code im using

```
<div id="grad1"></div>
```

Can anyone help, im lost with this!

Comment: It seams to be working on the other post, but why is my one not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put **image url** after the **gradient**, like so

```
#grad1 {
height: 200px;
background: rgba(255,0,0,1)), url(images/back3.gif); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
background: -o-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255,0,0,0), rgba(255,0,0,1)), url(http://lorempixel.com/600/800/sports/Dummy-Text/); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255,0,0,0), rgba(255,0,0,1)), url(http://lorempixel.com/600/800/sports/Dummy-Text/); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,0,0,0), rgba(255,0,0,1)), url(http://lorempixel.com/600/800/sports/Dummy-Text/); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
```

**[See in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rsr7j8jr/)**

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to do this:

[How do I combine a background-image and CSS3 gradient on the same element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504071/is-it-possible-to-combine-a-background-image-and-css3-gradients)

Use `background-image` instead.