# Create a gradient around a background image

Tags: css, image, gradient

I'm trying to apply a gradient effect **around** a background image but I just can't get close. I can figure out how to apply a gradient to the bottom of the  image. Can anyone help?

**Current code:**

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.backgroundImg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  size: contain;
  width: 1000;
  height: 10;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)))
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1000/dpo7WDOhWtACY6oflrqxutbhg81.jpg" class="backgroundImg">
</div>
```

**Expected Result:**
[image: Expected result]

Comment: Whats the problem? I can see the gradient.

Comment: I don't think I made myself clear enough. I want the gradient to surround the image.

Comment: Can you create a screenshot of how you want it to look? I find it different to visualise a gradient around something that is in the very top left corner. Also, you have errors in your CSS: the `width` and `height` properties lack units. And `-webkit-mask-image` works only in Chromium.

Comment: Something like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for: `-webkit-radial-gradient();`

For more info see: [CSS Visual Effects Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/SafariVisualEffectsProgGuide/Masks/Masks.html)

**Example:**

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
.backgroundImg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  size: contain;
  width: 1000;
  height: 10;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(white, transparent 80%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1000/dpo7WDOhWtACY6oflrqxutbhg81.jpg" class="backgroundImg">
</div>
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504071/is-it-possible-to-combine-a-background-image-and-css3-gradients?rq=1