# Combine CSS background-image and gradient on third h3 using nth-child

Tags: css, background-image, linear-gradients

I'm having a heck of a time trying to combine a diagonal linear gradient and regular `background-image` together *plus* apply it *only* to the second `h3` element; here is what I've got:

**HTML**

```
<div id="something">
  <div><h3>...</h3></div>
  <div><h3>...</h3></div>
  <div><h3>...</h3></div>
  <div><h3>...</h3></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#something h3:nth-child(2) {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(221,221,221,1) 0%,
  rgba(221,221,221,1) 95%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 95%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%),
  #ddd url(/assets/img/bullet.png) left 12px no-repeat;
}
```

I've had the `nth-child` selector working on other stuff previously before and this gradient is from an online generator, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the selector should be:

```
#something > div:nth-child(3) > h3
```

https://jsfiddle.net/db2n5r63/1/

Comment: awesome, glad to have helped! @John

Answer (score 1):

linear-gradient() takes the place of url(). In fact they are two delarations for the same background. One will be chosen. So define more precisely what you want and perhaps chose a span inside H3 to achieve the effect you want.

Answer (score 1):

Your `nth-child`wont work beacuse the `h3` tags are wrapped in a div so can you do something like this:

`#something div:nth-child(2) h3`

Now to make the background work we combine the background image url and the gradient. You can define the background url first then do a comma and define the gradient:

[**This**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504071/how-do-i-combine-a-background-image-and-css3-gradient-on-the-same-element) stackoverflow question answers that in more depth.

```
#something div:nth-child(2) h3{
  background:  url("http://lorempixel.com/300/300/") no-repeat,linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(221,221,221,1) 0%,
  rgba(221,221,221,1) 95%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 95%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
  background-position-x: 12px;
}
```

I've made an [**Example**](http://codepen.io/Ayeetu/pen/KzPxKG?editors=1100) for you to see this in action.