# How to tint background image in the css

Tags: html, css

I'm not quite sure how to do this. I have seen people say use `linear gradient` in the css under the background image url and add the rgba values but for some reason when I put `linear-gradient` in the css it doesn't work. When I type the code into my cms, it is white, while all the other working properties turn grey. (just to explain that it doesn't work) Here is my code. Hope this makes sense.

```
.topInfo {
    background-image: url('/CMS_Static/Uploads/313864614C6F6F/miami beach-1.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    height: 684px;
    linear-gradient: linear-gradient(rgba(#F9774C, .75), rgba(#802A0C, .85)),
}
```

Comment: `linear-gradient` is not a css property. What you need to do is put multiple background images in the `background-image` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**linear-gradient** is the property of **background** it should be something like

```
background: linear-gradient(rgba(249, 119, 76,.75), rgba(128, 42, 12,.85));
```

Refer more at https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by setting 2 backgrounds on the same element. First background needs to be a little transparent, so that you can see the other one below the first one. Linear background can also be a background, just like regular image. You can set multiple backgrounds with `,`.

Example:

```
body {
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0,255,0,0.4), rgba(255,0,0,0.2)),
    url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/41/Sol454_Marte_spirit.jpg);
}
```

You can see full example in action [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xXrBxj?editors=0100).

You can read and learn about `background-image` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image).

You can read and learn about `linear-gradient` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient).

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely possible, though not exactly the way you are trying to approach it. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4572733/3160385) for applying multiple backgrounds to an element. Note that the order in which these backgrounds are applied has an effect.

Pay attention to your color definitions. `rgba` accepts colors defined in RGB, not HEX values like you use. I [converted](https://www.webpagefx.com/web-design/hex-to-rgb/) your colors to RGB values:

```
#F9774C = rgb(249,119,76)
#802A0C = rgb(128,42,12)
```

Adding your desired alpha values to these and changing the format from `rgb` to `rgba`, your linear gradient is:

```
linear-gradient(rgba(249,119,76,.75), rgba(128,42,12,.85))
```

Check it out [here](https://codepen.io/Misacorp/pen/yzXZdg), but please give the answer linked above a read. It has useful information on browser compatibility and fallbacks.