# Microsoft Edge / IE browser Linear Gradient not working

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

What will be **Microsoft EDGE Browser alternatives** **of the following code?**

`background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(226, 115, 20, 0.64) 0%, #ea2415b3 100%)`

**I tried Following codes:**

`background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, rgba(226, 115, 20, 0.64) 0%, #ea2415b3 100%);`

`background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(to right, rgba(226, 115, 20, 0.64) 0%, #ea2415b3 100%);`

`background-image:         linear-gradient(to right, rgba(226, 115, 20, 0.64) 0%, #ea2415b3 100%);`

*Secondly*, I tried to insert **image and color in background but it displayed only color, not an image. I write this:**

`background : linear-gradient(0deg,#e97320,#000000),url(/img/Saturn_Astrologer.jpg) no-repeat center;`

**Thank You :)**

Comment: Please check this (invalid) value first: `#ea2415b3`? If you wanted both values to be rgba, than do so, it has to work.

Comment: @skobaljic it's not invalid: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-4/#hex-notation but probably still not supported everywhere

Comment: Let him just use regular color, as `linear-gradient(to right, rgba(226, 115, 20, 0.64) 0%, rgb(234, 36, 179) 100%)` and it will work fine, simply Edge won't byte `#ea2415b3`. Check [support for 8 digits hex](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-rrggbbaa).

Comment: @skobaljic It's working fine. Yes, in IE and Edge browser not supported eight digits hex color now.

Comment: @TemaniAfif this article helps me a lot.

Comment: Your comments are very useful to me. Thank you

Comment: @skobaljic I tried to put image and color in background but it displayed only color, not an image. I write this: `background : linear-gradient(0deg,#e97320,#000000),url(/img/Saturn_Astrologer.jpg) no-repeat center;`

Comment: When combine two or more, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504071/how-do-i-combine-a-background-image-and-css3-gradient-on-the-same-element