# how to apply background image to css gradient div?

Tags: html, css

```
<div>
  background image with gradient goes here
</div>

div{
background: rgb(0,170,175);
background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0,170,175,1) 0%, rgba(0,170,175,1) 35%, rgba(0,170,175,0.28) 100%);
background-image: url('https://cssgradient.io/images/css-gradient-swatches-a67daaf7.svg');
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "apply background image to css gradient div"?

Comment: a div should contain both properties gradient background and background image

Comment: Your question has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2547064/4584472

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine a gradient and a background image by putting them into the same (not seperate) `background` setting, separated by a comma:

```css
div{
height: 400px;
background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0,170,175,1) 0%, rgba(0,170,175,1) 35%, rgba(0,170,175,0.28) 100%), url('https://cssgradient.io/images/css-gradient-swatches-a67daaf7.svg');
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```