# How do you create a texture effect with css?

Tags: css

You can see it done here http://qunitjs.com/ and broken down here http://jsfiddle.net/xMwT8/8/ *edit (http://jsfiddle.net/xMwT8/9/)

links are available

- [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp)
- [here](http://forum.bytesforall.com/showthread.php?t=4538)
- [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/colors.html)
- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903659/why-i-cant-use-background-image-and-color-together)

I am trying to use an image as a texture with an overlay color above or combined with the image to blend into a subtle texture. It can be done with a gradient (like in the first and second link I posted). I don't understand why it won't work with just a color (2nd link).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *think* you are asking why you can't do this with a solid color like `#E4E2D6`.  The simple explanation is that it's a ***solid*** color :)

the jsfiddle example uses `rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3)` which isn't a solid color, it's a 70% transparent red (the `a == 0.3` means it's only 30% opacity)

If you want to do it with something like `#E4E2D6`, take a look at [Convert RGB to RGBA over white](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672374/convert-rgb-rgba) and convert it to `rgba(87, 74, 0, 0.16)` which is the same color (when displayed over white, but it's mostly transparent) and will allow the background through.

---

Okay, just looked at the `/9` fiddle (FYI you can just change the original link instead of putting an edit like that).  It seems that this doesn't work with

```
background: rgba( ... ), url( ... );
```

Why?  Because you can only have multiple background **images**.  The `-webkit-linear-gradient` *is* an image as far as the browser is concerned, so it uses both.  `rgba( ... )` without it is a color, so it uses the image and the color as a fallback

Comment: cheep cheep http://i1120.photobucket.com/albums/l493/powerfulcrunch/example1_zps774b3580.png | http://i1120.photobucket.com/albums/l493/powerfulcrunch/example2_zps9d9d11ea.png

Comment: Are you trying to ask something with those screenshots?  It needs to be a gradient because a gradient is an image and you can have multiple background __images__, but not a color and an image

Comment: youre right. the images have background-color still checked which is just what it was falling back to. to get the effect i want i would have to do overlays. thank you sir. - or the gradient solution