# CSS: background-image: is not displaying my image (First time making a website and first time using stack overflow)

Tags: html, css, http, url

As the title says Im really new and I was watching a youtube tutorial but my background-image doesnt display anything. The code is really symple and the url path is correct. Im not sure whats going on. Any suggestions?

```
/* home-info
========================== */

.home-info {
    background: url(C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\Programs\Websites\MyLife\images\aes.jpg);
    /* background-color: rgb(118, 182, 141); */
    padding: 10em 0;
    background-size: cover; 
}
```

this part of the code that is set to be a comment works fine.

```
/* background-color: rgb(118, 182, 141); */
```

I have tried putting ("..\aes.jpg"); and ('..\aes.jpg'); and it still doesnt work.
Could it be the image resolution it self (its 2048x1442)?

Also here is a part of my html code that has some meta inside

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <title>My Life</title>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

As far as I know that should allow the website to be resised without it looking weird and that also works.

Any suggestions are really appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Can you add folder structure? both image and css file path.

Comment: This helps to [add both image and color together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903659/why-cant-i-use-background-image-and-color-together)

Comment: Your `background-image` path should be relative your file. Try checking out the path under Network tab of your dev tools or even can see the path error in your windows' console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use the absolute path that's related to your computer, because it wont work elsewhere!

I think the problem comes from the use of `\` in your paths. Try replacing them by '/'. I don't know exactly about your folders architecture but try something like this : `images/aes.jpg`

Comment: Wow thank you. This worked. I have a question if you dont mind answering. Since I have a folder named "Websites" and inside i have multiple folders for different test websites named like "MyLife" and "Ariies" (Ariies folder has a empty index.html and a empty folder named images, while MyLife has my html code, folder also named images and styles.css) How does my css code know which images folder i want to use if my path is only set to images/aes.jpg. Does it search trough multiple images folder until it finds aes.jpg? Or does it search for the nearest one if that makes sense. Anyway thanks :D

Comment: When you are targeting 'images/aes.jpg', you are using a relative path. It is relative to the file in which style.css is open. So, when you open your `index.html` in `C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\Programs\Websites\MyLife`, the relative path directly targets `C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\Programs\Websites\MyLife\images\aes.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

You can not put the URL image like that all you have yo do is calling it from the folder that you have

```
 .home-info {
    // this is the right command to implement a background img.
        background-image: url("images\aes.jpg");

        padding: 10em 0;
        background-size: cover; 
    }
```

Comment: Hey, I tried background-image first but then I tried a lot of different solutions that I could find online. Sorry for the confusion but the comment above by ArnaudV worked. Seems it was a problem with my url path after all. Thank you for the reply anyway :D

Answer (score 0):

The below code would work..

```
background-image:url("images/aes.jpg");
```